# What are the pitfalls of ADL?

Tags: c++, namespaces, overload-resolution, argument-dependent-lookup

Some time ago I read an article that explained several pitfalls of argument dependent lookup, but I cannot find it anymore. It was about gaining access to things that you should not have access to or something like that. So I thought I'd ask here: what are the pitfalls of ADL?

Comment: Great relevant blog post by Arthur O’Dwyer on ambiguity issues on calls to `size` **due to ADL** as `std::size` [was added in C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size), see: [https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/06/17/std-size](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/06/17/std-size).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

There is a huge problem with argument-dependent lookup.  Consider, for example, the following utility:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace utility
{
    template <typename T>
    void print(T x)
    {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void print_n(T x, unsigned n)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            print(x);
    }
}
```

It's simple enough, right?  We can call `print_n()` and pass it any object and it will call `print` to print the object `n` times.

Actually, it turns out that if we only look at this code, we have *absolutely no idea* what function will be called by `print_n`.  It might be the `print` function template given here, but it might not be.  Why?  Argument-dependent lookup.

As an example, let's say you have written a class to represent a unicorn.  For some reason, you've also defined a function named `print` (what a coincidence!) that just causes the program to crash by writing to a dereferenced null pointer (who knows why you did this; that's not important):

```
namespace my_stuff
{
    struct unicorn { /* unicorn stuff goes here */ };

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, unicorn x) { return os; }

    // Don't ever call this!  It just crashes!  I don't know why I wrote it!
    void print(unicorn) { *(int*)0 = 42; }
}
```

Next, you write a little program that creates a unicorn and prints it four times:

```
int main()
{
    my_stuff::unicorn x;
    utility::print_n(x, 4);
}
```

You compile this program, run it, and... it crashes.  "What?!  No way," you say:  "I just called `print_n`, which calls the `print` function to print the unicorn four times!"  Yes, that's true, but it hasn't called the `print` function you expected it to call.  It's called `my_stuff::print`.

Why is `my_stuff::print` selected?  During name lookup, the compiler sees that the argument to the call to `print` is of type `unicorn`, which is a class type that is declared in the namespace `my_stuff`.

Because of argument-dependent lookup, the compiler includes this namespace in its search for candidate functions named `print`.  It finds `my_stuff::print`, which is then selected as the best viable candidate during overload resolution:  no conversion is required to call either of the candidate `print` functions and nontemplate functions are preferred to function templates, so the nontemplate function `my_stuff::print` is the best match.

(If you don't believe this, you can compile the code in this question as-is and see ADL in action.)

Yes, argument-dependent lookup is an important feature of C++.  It is essentially required to achieve the desired behavior of some language features like overloaded operators (consider the streams library).  That said, it's also very, very flawed and can lead to really ugly problems.  There have been several proposals to fix argument-dependent lookup, but none of them have been accepted by the C++ standards committee.

Comment: I should probably note that this example was inspired by a presentation on the subject that Bartosz Milewski gave; I don't have the slides from that presentation, and it's not exactly the same, but it's close.

Comment: Is this a pitfall of ADL or pitfall of not using ADL carefully?

Comment: @Chubsdad:  It's a huge pitfall of ADL.  The problem is that you can write two libraries that are totally independent and accidentally run into this problem without having any idea that you're going to have issues.  No amount of "carefulness" can completely protect you from this.

Comment: Nope, two independent libraries will never have this problem. You _have_ to write an explicit statement that mixes them, as in the example above. And even there, you see that the preference is for libraries not to mix: the mystuff-print is used with the mystuff-unicorn.

Comment: @MSalters:  Well, the problem is that the explicit statement that mixes the libraries isn't always so explicit.  Consider, e.g., if you write a namespace scope function template named `merge` that merges two things and you pass two it two `std::vector` objects.  You get different results depending on whether you've included `<algorithm>` (which declares `std::merge`).

Comment: How would a workaround look like? Implicitly use the current scope and only use ADL if explicitly requested and/or no match in current scope?

Comment: I would say this is not a pitfall but a feature: it lets you override a library behavior by providing an implementation specialized for your types. Without ADL, you wouldn't be able to modify `print`'s behavior to accomodate your `unicorn` type. A widely used application of this is `swap`: many standard algorithms need to swap values; you can provide your own optimized version of `swpa` and it will be selected thanks to ADL. Of course, it would be better if you could prevent this overriding when it is not wanted (the same way you are not mandated to make your member functions virtual).

Comment: But I agree that it can sometimes lead to unexcepted behavior. The user of a library needs to have a very good knowledge of a library she uses to avoid accidentaly overloading a function.

Comment: @LucTouraille "_it lets you **override** a library behavior by providing an implementation specialized for your types._" then every function is a customisation point. The sane default is that functions are not virtual unless explicitly marked virtual. "_many standard algorithms need to swap values; you can provide your own optimized version_" but the syntax for calling swap is ugly.

Comment: I think that either the documentation of `print_n()` should mention that it is calling `print()` multiple times (so that users are aware of ADL issues), or that `print()` should be wrapped in a `namespace detail`. In the code example that you gave, `print_n()` has an undocumented point of customization in the form of ADL on `print()`.

Comment: +1. But if it didn't call the crashing code i'd be seriously mad.

Comment: I think this is an argument to avoid `using namespace` (well, except for your own namespaces), not one against ADL. If you specify the namespace your reader and the compiler both understand you better. For the call to print from within print_n, you could specify the namespace or intend it as a customization point.

Comment: The question is why would the programmer write `print(x)` when he wants to call `::utility::print()`? If I write `print(x)`, then I *intend* to invoke ADL in order to *find* the correct overload (possibly in other namespaces too). If I don't want ADL, then I would write `::utility::print(x)`. So I don't *fully* agree with this answer. It mostly arises because of lack of *basic* knowledge about ADL. I would agree with @LucTouraille instead. :-)

Comment: Disagree. This answer is misguiding. It twists the very reason why ADL exists into a "problem". Please note, print(x) is not just "a function". It is a _template_, which accepts "anything". And additionally: the usage in print_n is _unqualified_. If someone really writes such arcane stuff, (s)he has to know the rules and play by the rules. And please don't complain about Unicorns. Why are you feeding Unicorns to your print_n template without verifying those where made to be treated this way?!

Comment: ADL can clearly cause serious trouble, but how can we prevent it? I have read somewhere an example where author uses a nested namespace and includes it in the parent namespace with `using nested_namespace` as a protection. Still, I can't get my head around how it would work in this example. Would I have to include the nested namespace in `my_stuff` or in `utility`?

Comment: Avoid ADL. Use namespace injection where the library's namespace allows.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is simply wrong - this is not a bug of ADL. It shows an careless anti-pattern to use function calls in daily coding - ignorance of dependent names and relying on unqualified function names blindly.

In short, if you are using unqualified name in the `postfix-expression` of a function call, you *should* have acknowledged that you have granted the ability that the function can be "overridden" elsewhere (yes, this is a kind of static polymorphism). Thus, the spelling of the unqualified name of a function in C++ is exactly a part of the *interface*.

In the case of the accepted answer, if the `print_n` really need ADL `print` (i.e. allowing it to be overridden), it should have been documented with the use of unqualified `print` as an explicit notice, thus clients would receive a contract that `print` should be carefully declared and the misbehavior would be all of the responsibility of `my_stuff`. Otherwise, it is a bug of `print_n`. The fix is simple: qualify `print` with prefix `utility::`. This is indeed a bug of `print_n`, but hardly a bug of the ADL rules in the language.

However, there *do* exist unwanted things in the language specification, and technically, not *only one*. They are realized more than 10 years, but nothing in the language is fixed yet. They are missed by the accepted answer (except that the last paragraph is solely correct till now). See this [paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0934r0.pdf) for details.

I can append one real case against the name lookup nasty. I was implementing `is_nothrow_swappable` where `__cplusplus < 201703L`. I found it impossible to rely on ADL to implementing such feature once I have a declared `swap` function template in my namespace. Such `swap` would always found together with `std::swap` introduced by a idiomatic `using std::swap;` to use ADL under the ADL rules, and then there would come ambiguity of `swap` where the `swap` template (which would instantiate `is_nothrow_swappable` to get the proper `noexcept-specification`) is called. Combined with 2-phase lookup rules, the order of declarations does not count, once the library header containing the `swap` template is included. So, unless I overload *all* my library types with specialized `swap` function (to supress any candidate generic templates `swap` being matched by overloading resolution after ADL), I cannot declare the template. Ironically, the `swap` template declared in my namespace is exactly to utilize ADL (consider `boost::swap`) and it is one of the most significant direct client of `is_nothrow_swappable` in my library (BTW, `boost::swap` does not respects the exception specification). This perfectly beat my purpose up, sigh...

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <iterator>

namespace my
{

#define USE_MY_SWAP_TEMPLATE true
#define HEY_I_HAVE_SWAP_IN_MY_LIBRARY_EVERYWHERE false

namespace details
{

using ::std::swap;

template<typename T>
struct is_nothrow_swappable
    : std::integral_constant<bool, noexcept(swap(::std::declval<T&>(), ::std::declval<T&>()))>
{};

} // namespace details

using details::is_nothrow_swappable;

#if USE_MY_SWAP_TEMPLATE
template<typename T>
void
swap(T& x, T& y) noexcept(is_nothrow_swappable<T>::value)
{
    // XXX: Nasty but clever hack?
    std::iter_swap(std::addressof(x), std::addressof(y));
}
#endif

class C
{};

// Why I declared 'swap' above if I can accept to declare 'swap' for EVERY type in my library?
#if !USE_MY_SWAP_TEMPLATE || HEY_I_HAVE_SWAP_IN_MY_LIBRARY_EVERYWHERE
void
swap(C&, C&) noexcept
{}
#endif

} // namespace my

int
main()
{
    my::C a, b;
#if USE_MY_SWAP_TEMPLATE

    my::swap(a, b); // Even no ADL here...
#else
    using std::swap; // This merely works, but repeating this EVERYWHERE is not attractive at all... and error-prone.

    swap(a, b); // ADL rocks?
#endif
}
```

Try https://wandbox.org/permlink/4pcqdx0yYnhhrASi and turn `USE_MY_SWAP_TEMPLATE` to `true` to see the ambiguity.

*Update 2018-11-05:*

Aha, I am bitten by ADL this morning again. This time it even has nothing to do with function calls!

Today I am finishing the work of porting [ISO C++17 `std::polymorphic_allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator) to my codebase. Since some container class templates have been introduced long ago in my code (like [this](https://bitbucket.org/FrankHB/yslib/src/4ed6f283887b299b36896e9438674eab61008ffa/YFramework/include/YCLib/Container.h?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#Container.h-82)), this time I just replace the declarations with alias templates like:

```
namespace pmr = ystdex::pmr;
template<typename _tKey, typename _tMapped, typename _fComp
    = ystdex::less<_tKey>, class _tAlloc
    = pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::pair<const _tKey, _tMapped>>>
using multimap = std::multimap<_tKey, _tMapped, _fComp, _tAlloc>;
```

... so it can use [my implementation of `polymorphic_allocator`](https://bitbucket.org/FrankHB/yslib/src/4ed6f283887b299b36896e9438674eab61008ffa/YBase/include/ystdex/memory_resource.h?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#memory_resource.h-334) by default. (Disclaimer: it has some known bugs. Fixes of the bugs would be committed in a few days.)

But it suddenly does not work, with hundreds of lines of cryptic error messages...

The error begins from [this line](https://bitbucket.org/FrankHB/yslib/src/4ed6f283887b299b36896e9438674eab61008ffa/YFramework/include/YSLib/Core/YMessage.h?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#YMessage.h-165). It roughly complains that the declared `BaseType` is not a base of the enclosing class `MessageQueue`. That seems very strange because the alias is declared with exactly the same tokens to those in the *base-specifier-list* of the class definition, and I am sure nothing of them can be macro-expanded. So why?

The answer is... ADL sucks. [The line inroducing `BaseType`](https://bitbucket.org/FrankHB/yslib/src/4ed6f283887b299b36896e9438674eab61008ffa/YFramework/include/YSLib/Core/YMessage.h?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#YMessage.h-159) is hard-coded with a `std` name as a template argument, so the template would be looked up per ADL rules *in the class scope*. Thus, it finds `std::multimap`, which differs to the result of lookup in as the actual base class declared *in the enclosing namespace scope*. Since `std::multimap` uses `std::allocator` instance as the default template argument, `BaseType` is not the same type to the actual base class which have an instance of `polymorphic_allocator`, even `multimap` declared in the enclosing namespace is redirected to `std::multimap`. By adding the enclosing qualification as the prefix right to the `=`, the bug is fixed.

I'd admit I am lucky enough. The error messages are heading the problem to this line. There are only 2 similar problems and [the other](https://bitbucket.org/FrankHB/yslib/src/4ed6f283887b299b36896e9438674eab61008ffa/YFramework/include/YSLib/UI/YStyle.h?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#YStyle.h-482) is without any explicit `std` (where `string` is [my own one](https://bitbucket.org/FrankHB/yslib/src/4ed6f283887b299b36896e9438674eab61008ffa/YBase/include/ystdex/string.hpp?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#string.hpp-71) being adapted to ISO C++17's `string_view` change, not `std` one in pre-C++17 modes). I would not figure out the bug is about ADL so quickly.

Comment: I think most people agree nowadays that the ADL rules as they were defined were a mistake (not ADL on itself). It is a chore to qualify all function calls for symbols in your own namespace (which in application code is most of them). It also hurts readability. The default should have been the opposite: mark explicitly which calls are meant to perform ADL.

Comment: @Acorn This may be better in the sense of [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), but if this have been true, I suspect there would have been a distinguishing syntax designed specifically for ADL. There might be other choices, though. Anyway, ADL is an overrider of the "usual" name lookup rules during translation, so why not some more general metaprogramming facilities to allow it being programmable (e.g. [hygienic macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro))? But sadly, this did not be taken account into the design.

Comment: That's why we have `std::ranges::swap` and the concept of CPO in C++20.