# inheritance and namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am trying a my first useful object oriented program with some namespace usage. 
I have a base class B which is in the namespace NS. If I try to inherit from this
base class to get the inheritance work, I should use the NS::B in the class decleration as below, is this really the case? Or is there a more widely accepted sytle for this inheritance syntax?

```
namespace NS
{
    class D: public NS::B{
    ...
    };
}
```

Best,
Umut

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your `D` is in `namespace NS`, you don't have to qualify `NS::B`, since `D` and `B` are in the same namespace. You can just use `class D : public B`.

Answer (score 8):

When you are inside of namespace `NS`, you don't usually<sup>(1)</sup> need to qualify the names of functions, classes, or other entities that are in the namespace `NS`.  Given:

```
namespace NS {
    class B { };
}
```

the following two definitions of `D` are the same:

```
namespace NS {
    class D : public NS::B { };
}
```

and:

```
namespace NS {
    class D : public B { };
}
```

---

(1)  Argument-Dependent Lookup (ADL) can cause some [ugly issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958648/what-are-the-pitfalls-of-adl), especially when using templates, and to fix them you may need to qualify names.

Comment: I guess I did a mistake somewhere in the makefile, this is what I would expect as well, thanks for the replies anyway.

Comment: @Umut: you can always try simple "what if" enquiries like this in a minimal single file.

Comment: How did you add the raised footnote?

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to denote NS since you are already inside it

```
namespace NS
{
    class D: public B{ //is fine
    };
}
```

Something else you might find interesting later is :

```
#include <iostream>
int x = 10;

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    //This will show the local x
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    //This is how you access the Global x
    std::cout << ::x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```