# Why GCC allows calling this function without using its namespace first?

Tags: c++, namespaces, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is "Argument-Dependent Lookup" (aka ADL, or "Koenig Lookup")?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8111677/9716597)
>   [Why does C++ parameter scope affect function lookup within a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392699/why-does-c-parameter-scope-affect-function-lookup-within-a-namespace)

Today I experienced this weird behavior. I can call strangeFn without `using namespace Strange` first, but does not allow calling strangeFn2 Why?

```
namespace Strange
{
    struct X
    {
    };
    void strangeFn(X&) {}
    void strangeFn2(int) {}
}

int main()
{
    Strange::X x;
    strangeFn(x);    // GCC allows calling this function.
    strangeFn2(0);   // Error: strangeFn2 is not declared in this scope.
    return 0;
}
```

How does C++ compilers resolve the scope of the symbols?

Answer (score 46):

This is called **[Argument Dependent Lookup (or Koenig Lookup)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup)**

Basically, if a symbol couldn't be resolved, the compiler will look into the namespace(s) of the argument(s).

The second function call fails, because `strangeFn2` isn't visible in the current namespace, neither is it defined  in the namespace of it's parameter type (`int`)

You can see how this works well with operator functions:

```
 std::complex<double> c, d;
 c += d; // wouldn't really work without ADL
```

or the ubiquitous iostream operators:

```
 std::string s("hello world");
 std::cout << s << std::endl; // Hello world would not compile without ADL...
```

For fun, this is what hello world would look like *without ADL* (and without `using` keyword...):

```
 std::string s("hello world");
 std::operator<<(std::cout, s).operator<<(std::endl); // ugly!
```

There are shadowy corner cases with ADL and overload resolution in the presence of function templates, but I'll leave them outside the scope of the answer for now.

Comment: Cool, didn't know this affected things as simple as "Hello World"...

Comment: Wow! One can never know C++ enough.

Comment: AFAIR namespaces of the arguments are always added to the search scope, not only if the name resolution fails (you can make an ambiguous call this way).

Comment: The code is buggy: `std::operator<<(std::operator<<(std::cout, s),  std::endl);` should be `std::operator<<(std::cout, s).operator<<(std::endl);`, see http://ideone.com/FFKA7b

Comment: @WorldSEnder It doesn't compile because **(a)** we didn't specify the necessary casts to disambiguate the template argument for `std::endl` **(b)** I accidentally used the free-function form for `operator<<` there. Avoiding to `.operator<<` was part of the point, but I realize that actually spelling out the pointer-to-member-function type there (including the parameter type for the manipulator) would not exactly make things clearer. So let me update the code with your compromise :)