# variables defined in a scope v.s. namespace variables injected in that scope

Tags: c++, scope, namespaces

When I run this code, it displays `6`...

```
#include <iostream>

namespace X {
    int  p = 5;
}

using namespace X;
int p = 6;

int main()
{
    std::cout << ::p;
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run this code, it displays `5`...

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Y {
    int  p = 16;
}

namespace X {
    int  p = 5;

    using namespace X;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << X::p;
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain what's happening there? Why am I not getting any error about ambiguity?

Comment: A variable declaration creates a *new* variable, hiding the one that's inherited from the namespace.

Comment: @Barmar so when I modify my first code and print just the variable p (without the scope operator) why I get an error then ?

Comment: I think it's because a declaration outside of a `namespace{}` block always defines a name in the global namespace -- you can't add to a namespace outside of it. But a *use* needs the scope operator to disambiguate it.

Comment: Did you mean for `X` to `using` itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your question itself. In the first example, you use...

```
std::cout << ::p;
```

That prepended `::` resolves namespaces in a specific order, **starting with the local namespace**. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4269064/472647)). Thus, it looks for `p` globally, locally, and *then* in an external namespace (`X`). Because it found `p` locally, it stops looking.

In the second example, you are *explicitly resolving* your namespace:

```
std::cout << X::p;
```

Thus, there's no search order to be bothered with. It is just going to look for `p` in the namespace `X`, and fail otherwise.

---

This leads to the second problem: you appear to be confusing the purpose of the `using namespace` keywords. Those are intended to enable you to use a more shorthand approach of resolving to a namespace, instead of always using the fully qualified name (`x::p`).

However, the computer will *still* look in the local namespace first, and THEN the `using` namespaces in the order they are found. As always, **once the computer finds the thing named in a namespace, it stops looking**.

---

This leads to a major principle in C++: **don't use `using namespace`!** There are exceptions, but you'll pick up on those as you work. The issue comes down to ambiguity as to what namespace something will be coming from, which is *exactly* the problem you described.

For example, imagine you define the namespaces `X` and `Y` in separate classes, and then you simply have the following...

```
#include "x.hpp"
#include "y.hpp"

using namespace x;
using namespace y;

int main()
{
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
}
```

Where'd `p` come from? Looking at `x.hpp` and `y.`hpp`, you see that BOTH have`p`, so which one is used? And then, what if you add`using namespace z;`above them? Now you have to check if`z`has`p`. ARGH!

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14136764/472647) for more information on namespace resolution.)

It is important to note that, as far as the compiler/linker are concerned, there *is* no ambiguity. It has an implicit resolution order to handle that. The ambiguity is all on the coder.

Even worse, what if you define `q` locally, without realizing that `x` or `y` have a `q` as well? What will it resolve to?

**This is a situation you *never* want to create!** Borrowing from Tim Peter's *Zen of Python* (albeit, different language, but some of the principles therein are true in most languages)...

> Explicit is better than implicit.

So, how can we write this to be less wibbly-wobbly timey-wimey?

1. **Drop** `using namespace`. The only time you should even touch this is if you are using a *bunch* of stuff from one namespace, and virtually *nothing* from anywhere else. (You'll notice most C++ programmers won't even do `using namespace std;`)
2. Use the **fully qualified name** on anything you use sparingly-to-moderately. For example, `x::p`.
3. If you use something a *lot*, use the command `using x::p` at the top of the file. This resolves `p` to `namespace x`, without confusing everything else.

In short, you should be able to tell, at a glance, what namespace *everything* comes from. **Never** create a situation of ambiguity and implicit resolution; only bugs and pain lie that way.

Comment: A prepended :: starts looking at the global namespace, not local.

Comment: in the second case, when I remove the explicit definition and leave the using , it will print 16, how can I understand that ?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, thanks for the correction, I've edited. Globally, locally, and then onward, yes?

Comment: @HovhannesVardanyan, do you mean, in the second example you gave?

Comment: Yes @CodeMouse92

Comment: @HovhannesVardanyan Well, assuming that is one code file (no reason to believe otherwise), the first one declared wins out because it's locally declared, and the resolution is then following basic first-come-first-served. There just wasn't an error because each was in its own namespace. By the by, don't do that.