# sorting a vector of std::pair<int, std::unique_ptr<const T> > depending on pair.first

Tags: c++, sorting, smart-pointers, move-semantics

I'm trying to sort a vector of pairs containing a smart pointers of a const object. I'm trying to sort only depending on the first object. Below you see (one of my numerous attempts to write) code that is supposed to do this, alongside with an excerpt from the error.

The compiler complains about the lambda parameters. I've tried to make the parameters const, non-const, references, rvalue-references, to no avail. Help please?

```
std::pair<int, std::unique_ptr<const std::string> > a;
auto uniq = std::make_unique<const std::string>("hurz");
a = std::make_pair(1,std::move(uniq));

std::pair<int, std::unique_ptr<const std::string> > b;
uniq = std::make_unique<const std::string>("hurz");
b = std::make_pair(2,std::move(uniq));

std::vector<std::pair<int,std::unique_ptr<const std::string> > > vec;

vec.push_back(std::move(a));
vec.push_back(std::move(b));

std::sort(std::make_move_iterator(vec.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(vec.end()),
    []
    (const std::pair<int,std::unique_ptr<const std::string> >& i1,
     const std::pair<int,std::unique_ptr<const std::string> >& i2)
    { return i1.first > i2.first;});
```

The error message didn't help me:

```
error: no matching function for call to 
'swap(std::move_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, 
std::unique_ptr<const std::basic_string<char> > >*, std::vector<std::pair<int, 
std::unique_ptr<const std::basic_string<char> > > > > >::value_type, 
std::move_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, 
std::unique_ptr<const std::basic_string<char> > >*, std::vector<std::pair<int, 
std::unique_ptr<const std::basic_string<char> > > > > >::value_type)' swap(*__a, 
*__b);
candidates are:
 /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/move.h:166:5: note: void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) 
[with _Tp = std::pair<int, std::unique_ptr<const std::basic_string<char> > >]

plus many more errors in the same vein
```

Comment: Why do you need a `std::unique_ptr<const std::string>` instead of simply `std::string` at all?

Comment: the string is just an example. I have objects that i pass around and would like garbage collected once it goes out of scope.

Comment: _"I have objects that i pass around ..."_ That's an indicator you need a `std::shared_ptr` instead of `std::unique_ptr`. Check out their concepts of ownership.

Comment: i never hold the object in two places at once and the performance hit of shared_ptr is too large in my application.

Comment: @NathanOliver [Same result here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/334fc65d1c075402)

Comment: Why would you ever want to pass a `move_iterator` to `std::sort`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is the use of `std::make_move_iterator`.  When you do so you turn the iterators into `move_iterator`'s which means when you dereference them you get a `T&&`, instead of a `T&` like you do with normal iterators.

`std::swap`, which is used in your implementation of `std::sort` only takes lvalue references so it cannot bind to the dereferenced iterator.  If you use

```
std::sort(vec.begin(),
    vec.end(),
    []
    (const std::pair<int,std::unique_ptr<const std::string> >& i1,
     const std::pair<int,std::unique_ptr<const std::string> >& i2)
    { return i1.first > i2.first;});
```

instead then you will have lvalues for `std::swap` to bind to and `std::swap` will work for move only types

Comment: thanks for both solution and for the explanation why it couldn't work with move_iterator!

Answer (score 1):

I add some further explanation to the answer of @NathanOliver which is too long for a comment. I guess the OP's idea of using

```
std::sort(std::make_move_iterator(vec.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(vec.end()),
    [](const std::pair<int,std::unique_ptr<const std::string> >& i1,
       const std::pair<int,std::unique_ptr<const std::string> >& i2)
       { return i1.first > i2.first;});
```

i.e., with a `move_iterator` applied to `vector.begin()`, is to use move assignments (and not copies) inside the sorting routine. This idea is tempting, but it's not necessary because inside  `std::sort`, assignments are usually done with `std::swap` which [tries to move arguments passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25286610/2412846).

On the other hand, for algorithms which use input and output iterators, such as most basically `std::copy` or `std::copy_if`, the use of `std::make_move_iterator` can be quite useful. Those often use constructs like `*output_it = *input_it`, and together with `std::make_move_iterator` this corresponds to `*output_it = std::move(*input_it)`, so the move-assignment operator of the type dereferenced by `*output_it` could be used.