# Is there any pre-defined method to swap two elements?

Tags: java

If we have to swap two elements in java then we can swap them using a temporary variable.

```
  int temp=a;
  a=b;
  b=temp;
```

Also, we can do it by using different ways also but is there any predefined method like C++ that have `std::swap()`?

In the collection, we have `swap()` but it only works for the `list`.

Comment: This _can't_ be done, because Java is strictly pass-by-value.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no pre-defined function that swaps two elements. And for good reason. Java is always `pass-by-value`. Not like C++, where you can choose whether to give the value or the reference of the variable to the function.

If you want to read more about pass-by-value / pass-by-reference, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/7954021) answer covers pretty much everything.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that without using a temporary variable.
Even C++ implementation of `std::swap()` uses a temporary variable inside, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286544/how-does-the-standard-library-implement-stdswap).

If you really want to you can wrap this code in a method and just call it.

This is just for fun but if you **really** want to swap integers, you can do it like so:

```
int a = 100;
int b = 25;
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

Comment: Or, using the xor operator: `a = a ^ b; b = a ^ b; a = a ^ b;`