# Defining a function with the type of a class defined within another class

Tags: c++, class

```
class A {
    class B { }
    B somefunction();
}

B A::somefunction() {
   B bla;
   return bla;
}
```

So I have something similar to this in my code. And I am getting an error saying that `'B' does not name a type`. Any help would be appreciated. P.S. I am not allowed to change the interface.

Comment: Because B is not visible outside A.

Comment: Sorry for the abstraction but this is a part of an assignment so I only needed to clarify some concept. Otherwise it would be immoral. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A leading return type is interpreted outside the scope of the function; so nested types need to be qualified if used there:

```
A::B A::somefunction() {
```

Alternatively, since C++11, you could use a trailing return type, which (like function parameter types) is interpreted in the scope of the function:

```
auto A::somefunction() -> B {
```

Comment: I liked that you used trailing return types :D

Comment: Might be worth referencing [ADL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup)?

Comment: @matsjoyce: There's no ADL here, since no function is being called. This is qualified lookup in the first example, and unqualified lookup (in a suitable scope) in the second.

Answer (score 0):

`B` is scoped to `A`, so in order to refer to `B` you need use the scope resolution operator: `A::B`.

So something like `A::B A::somefunction()` for your definition of `somefunction` should work.

Answer (score 0):

B is in the A class, and behaves kindof as if it is in an A namespace. Try:

```
class A {
    class B { }
    B somefunction();
}

A::B A::somefunction() {
   B bla;
   return bla;
}
```

Comment: `A` isn't a _namespace_, it's just `B` being a nested class.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of `somefunction()` should look like

```
 A::B A::somefunction() {
   B bla;
   return bla;
 }
```

Comment: While certainly not wrong, I do believe the the A:: is unnecessary before bla.

Comment: @Pure THX for the attention, but _@MikeSeymoure_'s answer explains more in depth what's actually going on.