# Separate declaration for friend function

Tags: c++

I am reading C++ Primer book. It says:

*A friend declaration only specifies access. It is not a general declaration of the
function. If we want users of the class to be able to call a friend function, then we
must also declare the function separately from the friend declaration.
To make a friend visible to users of the class, we usually declare each friend
(outside the class) in the same header as the class itself.*

Watch out for arrow in the code. Which asks my questions at those particular points in reference to above text.

header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Husband{
    friend void change_salary(int changed_salary, Husband &ob);

public:
    Husband() {}
    Husband(unsigned new_salary) : salary{ new_salary } {}

private:
    int salary;

};

//void change_salary(int changed_salary, Husband &ob);  <----Code Compiles without even this declaration

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

void change_salary(int changed_salary, Husband &ob)
{
    cout << "salary increased by 1000";
    ob.salary = changed_salary;
}


int main()
{
    Husband hs1{ 3000 };

    change_salary(4000, hs1);  // <---- Able to use function without explicit declaration outside of class in header

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Try moving the definition of `change_salary` to `husband.cpp`. You will need to declare the function in `husband.h` then.

Comment: @AustinMullins now i kept change_salary code in husband.cpp and included "header.h" .....even then my main.cpp compiles correctly without even separate declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a prototype in the header file if you use the function in the same file it is declared in, after it was declared, which is what you did in main.cpp.

Putting a prototype in the header file helps code in *other* files, or in the same file but higher up, find the function. It is often a good practice to create a prototype in the header file to make the API clear to human readers. But in the case you have here, it is not strictly required to compile.

Comment: so that means i may or may not have it(my choice)? but if i go with proper systematic way then i must have it?

Comment: The C compiler will try a few things to find your function before throwing an error, so it may actually compile with a warning about "implicit declaration".

Comment: You're right that a C compiler would warn about implicit declaration if a function is used without a prior visible declaration/definition, but a C++ compiler would throw an error at that point. (cc @androidplusios.design)

Answer (score 1):

A friend function declaration is part of your your class design. Without a declaration of the function in your class header (or some included header) your design is incomplete (enforces a user to implement that function or opens the door for some user implementation or causing a one-definition-rule (ODR) violation).

Answer (score 1):

You've provided the definition of `change_salary` before the definition of `main()` which uses it, so the function is always visible and there are no issues. But let's say you move the definition below that of `main()` (or to a separate .cpp file).

```
int main()
{
    Husband hs1{ 3000 };
    change_salary(4000, hs1);
}

void change_salary(int changed_salary, Husband &ob)
{
    cout << "salary increased by 1000";
    ob.salary = changed_salary;
}
```

The code will continue to compile even in this case because `change_salary` will be found by [argument dependent name lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8111677/241631) (because the second argument is of type `Husband&`).

Now let's try to explicitly refer to `change_salary` by forming a pointer to it within `main()`.

```
void (*p)(int, Husband&) = &change_salary;
```

This will [fail to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99bc569e3c62152c) because ADL does not apply in this case, and the definition of `change_salary` is not visible to `main()`.

However, if you uncomment the declaration of `change_salary` within the header, the [code will compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82b13ed6b66a227f). This is presumably what the book meant when it said *To make a friend visible to users of the class*.