# Error: no match for 'operator==' for boost::tuple

Tags: c++, boost, operator-overloading

I intend to define a custom `operator==` for `boost::tuple`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
//#include <boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp>

/*namespace boost { namespace tuples {*/
bool operator==(const boost::tuple<int>&, const boost::tuple<int>&){
  return false;    
}
/*}}*/

int main(){
  boost::tuple<int> t, u;      
  std::vector<boost::tuple<int> > vec;

  std::cout << (t == u); // [1]

  find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), t); // [2]
}
```

While this works for [1], it fails for [2] with the following error:

```
/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/predefined_ops.h:191:17: error:
no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'boost::tuples::tuple<int>'
and 'const boost::tuples::tuple<int>')
  { return *__it == _M_value; }
```

So, my question is, why does the compiler not look for `operator==` in the global namespace in the case of `std::find`.

NB: it works if i place the `operator==` in namespace `boost::tuples` as shown in the comments above.

Comment: Rather than editing this older solved question, please post a new one and if you think it's helpful include a link to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should include an additional file:

```
#include "boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp"
```

Since the operators are defined in a separate header.

The reason that it doesn't look in the global namespace is due to the rules of ADL, which will only look in the `boost::tuples` namespace (where the tuple is defined), and the `std` namespace.

Read [What is “Argument-Dependent Lookup” (aka ADL, or “Koenig Lookup”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup) for more info

Comment: hey.. the link you pointed to says and i quote `The algorithm (ADL) tells the compiler to not just look at local scope, but also the namespaces that contain the argument's type`... isn't the custom `operator ==` here essentially in the local scope or is there something i am missing?

Comment: @user1055604   The problem is that the failure is occurring when it's in std::find's scope, not your own.  So in this case, it would only search the boost and std namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

`ADL`. When you just use `operator ==` in your code - `namespace boost::tuples` and `global namespace` are processed.
But, since find is in std namespace only `std` and `boost::tuples` will be processed.