# Ambiguous call to std/boost move

Tags: c++, boost

Came across this code which doesn't compile:

```
#include <boost/move/utility.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <deque>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    typedef std::pair<int, std::deque<int>> FirstPair;
    typedef std::vector<FirstPair> VectorFirstPair;
    typedef std::pair<boost::posix_time::time_duration, VectorFirstPair> SecondPair;
    typedef std::map<boost::posix_time::time_duration, SecondPair> Map;
    Map mapInstance;
    SecondPair newElement = make_pair(boost::posix_time::not_a_date_time, VectorFirstPair());
    mapInstance.insert(make_pair(boost::posix_time::seconds(10), move(newElement))).first;
}
```

This fails on gcc 4.8.2 using boost 1.55 (not on boost 1.54) with the following error (ideone [here](http://ideone.com/pjbnVo)):

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:17:81: error: call of overloaded ‘move(SecondPair&)’ is ambiguous
     mapInstance.insert(make_pair(boost::posix_time::seconds(10), move(newElement))).first;
                                                                                 ^
test.cpp:17:81: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/utility:70,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config/no_tr1/utility.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config/select_stdlib_config.hpp:37,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config.hpp:40,
                 from /usr/include/boost/move/detail/config_begin.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/include/boost/move/utility.hpp:17,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/move.h:101:5: note: constexpr typename std::remove_reference< <template-parameter-1-1> >::type&& std::move(_Tp&&) [with _Tp = std::pair<boost::posix_time::time_duration, std::vector<std::pair<int, std::deque<int> > > >&; typename std::remove_reference< <template-parameter-1-1> >::type = std::pair<boost::posix_time::time_duration, std::vector<std::pair<int, std::deque<int> > > >]
     move(_Tp&& __t) noexcept
     ^
In file included from test.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/boost/move/utility.hpp:138:55: note: typename boost::remove_reference<T>::type&& boost::move(T&&) [with T = std::pair<boost::posix_time::time_duration, std::vector<std::pair<int, std::deque<int> > > >&; typename boost::remove_reference<T>::type = std::pair<boost::posix_time::time_duration, std::vector<std::pair<int, std::deque<int> > > >]
          inline typename remove_reference<T>::type && move(T&& t) BOOST_NOEXCEPT
```

Shouldn't this compile? Shouldn't the `using namespace` clause make this unambiguous? Why is the compiler choosing `boost::move` as a viable candidate here?

Note that this doesn't cause any errors if I remove the `boost` types in the types defined (replacing them with e.g. `int`).

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8111892/3102935. It is because of ADL

Comment: So ADL uses template parameters too? I thought it only used the top level type (`std::pair` in this case)

Comment: "The sets of namespaces and classes is determined
entirely by the types of the function arguments (and the namespace of any template template argument)." §3.4.2.2

Comment: Damn, thanks. If you turn that comment into an answer, I'll accept it :). Do you know what's the rationale behind this? I know what ADL is for, but why also take template parameters into account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of ADL - argument dependant lookup (see this [answer](/a/8111892/3102935) which is also boost related).

The problem is that the namespace `boost` is considered because:

> § 3.4.2 Argument-dependent name lookup
>
> 2. ... The sets of namespaces and classes is determined entirely by the types of the function arguments (and the namespace of any template template argument). ...

Thus, because some boost-related type is a template argument of `std::pair`, `boost::move` is also considered. (imho it shouldn't because I can't figure out how to program around that ambiguity).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to explicitly qualifying `std::move` everywhere, you can define `BOOST_MOVE_USE_STANDARD_LIBRARY_MOVE`, which just aliases `boost::move` to `std::move`. With that, [your example compiles successfully](http://ideone.com/CscuL4).