# Using boost::program_options with std::optional

Tags: boost, boost-program-options, stdoptional

Boost's `program_options` library now [supports](https://github.com/boostorg/program_options/pull/18/files) boost::optional, can the same be done with `std::optional`?

I attempted to modify both the [documentation example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#idm45927870445216) and the code in the PR, but neither seems to work.

For example, the very simple case for integers (before trying template specializations):

```
void validate(boost::any& v, const std::vector<std::string>& values, std::optional<int>* target_type,
              int) {
  using namespace boost::program_options;
  validators::check_first_occurrence(v);
  const string& s = validators::get_single_string(values);

  int n = lexical_cast<int>(s);
  v = any(std::make_optional<int>(n));
}
```

fails with the error that the target type is not `istream`able:

```
external/boost/boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical.hpp:243:13: 
error: static_assert failed due to requirement 
'has_right_shift<std::__1::basic_istream<char>, std::__1::optional<int>, boost::binary_op_detail::dont_care>::value || boost::has_right_shift<std::__1::basic_istream<wchar_t>, std::__1::optional<int>, boost::binary_op_detail::dont_care>::value'
"Target type is neither std::istream`able nor std::wistream`able"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with things like `validate` (and `operator>>` as well) is often [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)¹.

You need to declare the overload in one of the *associated namespaces*. In this case, because `int` is a primitive type, the only associated namespaces come from library code:

- `std` for `optional`, `vector`, `string`, `allocator`, `char_traits` (yes these all count!)
- `boost` for `any`

You'd prefer not to add your code in those namespaces, because you might interfere with library functions or invite future breakage when the library implementation details change.

If you had to choose, you'd prefer to choose `boost` here, because

- that's the library providing the feature at hand
- the `validate` free function is *explicitly* designed to be an customization point

> Sidenote: Keep an eye out for [`tag_invoke`](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/hhvwgt/tag_invoke_an_actually_good_way_to_do/) - a better way to build customization points in libraries

---

### The Fix

After all this verbiage, the solution is very simple:

```
namespace boost {
    void validate(boost::any& v, const std::vector<std::string>& values,
                  std::optional<int>*, int) {
        using namespace boost::program_options;
        validators::check_first_occurrence(v);
        const std::string& s = validators::get_single_string(values);

        int n = boost::lexical_cast<int>(s);
        v     = boost::any(std::make_optional<int>(n));
    }
} // namespace boost
```

Adding two lines made it work: [Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RxLQmoXSBg5vMl9C).

### Other Notes:

1. The "solution" injecting `operator>>` in general is less pure
   because

   - it has a potential to "infect" all other code with ADL-visible overloads that might interfere. Way more code uses `operator>>` than
     boost's `validate` function
   - it thereby invites [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to
     [ODR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) violations,
     when another translation unit, potentially legitimely, defines
     another `operator>>` for the same arguments.
2. On recent compilers you can say `vm.contains` instead of the slightly abusive `vm.count`
3. There's another snag with non-streamable types, where, if you define a default value, you probably also need to specify the *string representation* with it.

### Listing

**[Compiling on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/eTbx8c)**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

namespace boost {
    void validate(boost::any& v, const std::vector<std::string>& values,
                std::optional<int>*, int) {
        using namespace boost::program_options;
        validators::check_first_occurrence(v);
        const std::string& s = validators::get_single_string(values);

        int n = boost::lexical_cast<int>(s);
        v     = boost::any(std::make_optional<int>(n));
    }
} // namespace boost

int main(int ac, char* av[]) {
    try {
        using Value = std::optional<int>;

        po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
        desc.add_options()
            ("help", "produce help message")
            ("value", po::value<Value>()->default_value(10, "10"),
                "value")
        ;

        po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
        po::notify(vm);

        if (vm.contains("value")) {
            std::cout << "value is " << vm["value"].as<Value>().value() << "\n";
        }

    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

---

### BONUS

As an added exercise, let's demonstrate that if your optional value_type is **not** a primitive, but rather your library type, declared in a namespace `MyLib`, then we don't have most of the trade-offs above:

```
namespace MyLib {
    template <typename T> struct MyValue {
        MyValue(T v = {}) : value(std::move(v)) {}

      private:
        T value;
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, MyValue& mv) {
            return is >> mv.value;
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyValue const& mv) {
            return os << mv.value;
        }
    };
```

Now you could provide generic validators for any types in your MyLib namespace, be it optional or not, and have ADL find them through your `MyLib` namespace:

```
    template <typename T, typename Values>
    void validate(boost::any& v, Values const& values, T*, int) {
        po::validators::check_first_occurrence(v);
        v = boost::lexical_cast<T>(
                po::validators::get_single_string(values));
    }

    template <typename T, typename Values>
    void validate(boost::any& v, Values const& values, std::optional<T>*, int) {
        po::validators::check_first_occurrence(v);
        v = std::make_optional(
                boost::lexical_cast<T>(
                    po::validators::get_single_string(values)));
    }
} // namespace MyLib
```

See **[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8fpnF6Syngdq9Cnz)**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

namespace MyLib {
    template <typename T> struct MyValue {
        MyValue(T v = {}) : value(std::move(v)) {}

      private:
        T value;
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, MyValue& mv) {
            return is >> std::boolalpha >> mv.value;
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyValue const& mv) {
            return os << std::boolalpha << mv.value;
        }
    };

    // Provide generic validators for any types in your MyLib namespace, be it
    // optional or not
    template <typename T, typename Values>
    void validate(boost::any& v, Values const& values, T*, int) {
        po::validators::check_first_occurrence(v);
        v = boost::lexical_cast<T>(
                po::validators::get_single_string(values));
    }

    template <typename T, typename Values>
    void validate(boost::any& v, Values const& values, std::optional<T>*, int) {
        po::validators::check_first_occurrence(v);
        v = std::make_optional(
                boost::lexical_cast<T>(
                    po::validators::get_single_string(values)));
    }
} // namespace MyLib

int main(int ac, char* av[]) {
    try {
        using Int    = MyLib::MyValue<int>;
        using OptInt = std::optional<MyLib::MyValue<int>>;
        using OptStr = std::optional<MyLib::MyValue<std::string> >;

        po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
        desc.add_options()
            ("ival", po::value<Int>()->default_value(Int{10}),
                  "integer value")
            ("opti", po::value<OptInt>()->default_value(OptInt{}, "(nullopt)"),
                  "optional integer value")
            ("sval", po::value<OptStr>()->default_value(OptStr{"secret"}, "'secret'"),
                  "optional string value")
        ;

        po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
        po::notify(vm);

        std::cout << "Options: " << desc << "\n";

        if (vm.contains("ival")) {
            std::cout << "ival is " << vm["ival"].as<Int>() << "\n";
        }
        if (vm.contains("opti")) {
            if (auto& v = vm["opti"].as<OptInt>())
                std::cout << "opti is " << v.value() << "\n";
            else
                std::cout << "opti is nullopt\n";
        }
        if (vm.contains("sval")) {
            if (auto& v = vm["sval"].as<OptStr>())
                std::cout << "sval is " << v.value() << "\n";
            else
                std::cout << "sval is nullopt\n";
        }
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

For `./a.out  --ival=42 --sval=LtUaE` prints:

```
Options: Allowed options:
  --ival arg (=10)        integer value
  --opti arg (=(nullopt)) optional integer value
  --sval arg (='secret')  optional string value

ival is 42
opti is nullopt
sval is LtUaE
```

---

¹ see also See also [Why Does Boost Use a Global Function Override to Implement Custom Validators in "Program Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412474/why-does-boost-use-a-global-function-override-to-implement-custom-validators-in/31416234#31416234)

Comment: [Added](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66548554/revisions) a BONUS "chapter" showing how to reduce the concessions by leveraging ADL for your own namespaces, with more generalizations. **[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8fpnF6Syngdq9Cnz)**

Comment: What a fantastic answer. Thank you for answering the question I have now *and* the question I'll have soon (next week, I gather).