# visibility outside namespace propagated by usage of other namespace elements

Tags: c++

Take a look at this simple snippet:

```
namespace Test
{
    struct A {};
    void foo( A _a ) {}
}


int main( int, char** )
{
    foo( Test::A() ); // 1. why foo doesn't require Test:: ?
    Test::foo( A() ); // 2. why A() requires Test:: considering above line?

    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned in the source:

1. `foo( Test::A() );` why `foo` doesn't require `Test::` here?
2. `Test::foo( A() );` why `A()` requires `Test::` considering above line?

(Visual Studio 2008 and [gcc4.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3d1aad2392d8fde) give the same result, so I suppose this is standard behavior, but I'm wondering which part of standard defines it?)

Comment: I do not understand your 2nd point: " why A() requires Test:: considering above line?" ... in your second line, there is no `Test::` in front of `A()` ....

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, and because of that it doesn't compile. You need to add Test:: to compile it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Argument-dependent name lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup), a.k.a. Koenig lookup (although [Andrew Koenig did not invent it](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/a-personal-note-about-argument-dependent/232901443)). It is defined in the chapter of the same name in the standard.

It enables things like:

```
std::string str( "Hello world!" );
std::cout << str;
```

The overload `operator<<( std::ostream &, std::string )` is in the `std::` namespace -- and without ADL, *it would not be found*.

It works *only* for functions looked for in the namespace of their arguments, not the other way around (your example 2), which would *further* weaken namespace barriers with no comparable benefit to case 1.

---

More in-depth discussion of the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/).

Comment: I knew I read about it but I couldn't to find the right topic. Thanks!