# implicit namespace resolution in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces

I wonder why the following snipped of C++ code compiles without error:

```
namespace ns {
    struct foo {};
    void stuff(void*x) {}
}
int main() {
    ns::foo x;
    stuff(&x);
}
```

I thought that it must be obligatory to put a namespace qualifier in front of `stuff`, and indeed if I replace the variable x with `int x`, then the error arises. It appears that the compiler deduces the namespace to which `stuff` belongs from the type of its argument, which doesn't make sense to me. Tested with GCC 4.2.1 and 4.8.3

Comment: Due to argument dependent lookup (ADL). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup

Comment: ADL indeed. Declare the x inside main as int and you get a compilation error.