# Visual Studio warning about function not in global namespace

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I didn't really know what to write in the title, but basically I have a single .cpp, with only standard library headers included and no "using" keywords. I made my own "generate(...)" function. After including the  library, Visual Studio shows me an error (where the function is being called), basically saying that it doesn't know whether to choose std::generate(...) or generate(...) because they have matching argument lists.

Is this a bug or have I missed something? I might also add that I am using VS2015.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename Iter, typename Function>
Function generate(Iter begin, Iter end, Function f)
{
    while (begin != end)
    {
        *begin = f();
        ++begin;
    }
    return f;
}

class Random
{
public:
    Random(int low, int high)
        : mLow(low), mHigh(high)
    {}

    int operator()()
    {
        return mLow + rand() % (mHigh - mLow + 1);
    }

private:
    int mLow;
    int mHigh;
};

class Print
{
    void operator()(int t)
    {
        std::cout << t << " ";
    }
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    std::vector<int> intVec;
    intVec.resize(15);

    Random r(2, 7);
    generate(intVec.begin(), intVec.end(), r);
}
```

Error output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Functor, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Main.cpp
1>c:\users\michael sund\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\gi_cpp\functor\main.cpp(44): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\michael sund\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\gi_cpp\functor\main.cpp(50): error C2668: 'generate': ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>  c:\users\michael sund\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\gi_cpp\functor\main.cpp(7): note: could be 'Function generate<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>,Random>(Iter,Iter,Function)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Function=Random,
1>              Iter=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\algorithm(1532): note: or       'void std::generate<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>,Random>(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,_Fn0)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _FwdIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>,
1>              _Fn0=Random
1>          ]
1>  c:\users\michael sund\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\gi_cpp\functor\main.cpp(50): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>, std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>, Random)'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code, preferably an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ... and the error text *verbatim*.

Comment: You've answered your own question: you have two functions with the same name and same signature.  Use `::generate()` to tell the compiler you want "your version".  Better, consider creating your own namespace.  Or giving your function a different name.

Comment: And do not do using std.

Comment: I am NOT using std...

Comment: If you woudn't be using std; there would be know ambiguity between your generate and std::generate.

Comment: Exactly, so what's going on? I'll post the whole code so you can see.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens on not just VC++ (VS 2015), but g++ 4.9+ as well. The issue here is the tricky [Argument Dependent Lookup (Koenig Lookup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup).

It looks at the two iterators you're adding and it sees the "generate" function in `std` because the iterators also come from the `std` namespace (this is the point of Argument Dependent Lookup).

This problem actually bit me at one point: when I wrote my own [`tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) implementation that did a few things extra to `tie`. I had to call mine [`tye`](https://github.com/ThePhD/Furrovine.Heart/blob/e37b03c3ac73ef9a3bb8e1e8769d5d1bf68c7493/include/Furrovine%2B%2B/tye.hpp) because Koenig Lookup caused the considered overloads to be equal in their ranking and thus cause an error like this.

Either prefix generate with `::` to start lookup from the global namespace (`::generate( vec.begin(), vec.end(), ... );`), or name it differently.