# Why the c++ function `getline` doesn't need `std::` to be in front of it?

Tags: c++

I compiled and ran a sample code of `getline`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

main ()
{
  std::string name;

  std::cout << "Please, enter your full name: ";
  std::getline (std::cin,name);
  std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";

  return 0;
}
// from `http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/`
```

I replaced `std::getline` to `getline`, but it still works. Why is it?

Comment: See [ADL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup).

Comment: I see there are many duplicate questions like this one. What should I do now? Delete this question? Or wait until somebody mark this as duplicate?

Comment: @JennyaChang: no harm having some duplicates around, as they may get found by poeple using different search terms, and lead them to the answer they need.  Cheers.