# specialize std::greater via std::rel_ops

Tags: c++, compare, std

How I can specialize `std::greater` by using `std::rel_ops`?
I have something like this

```
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

using namespace std::rel_ops;

struct MyStruct {
    int field;
    bool operator < (const MyStruct& rhs) const {
        return field < rhs.field;
    }
};
```

So I need to sort elements in descending order. How I can do it by using `operator <`, `std::rel_ops` and `std::greater`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you tried to do something similar to

```
MyStruct ms[] = {{10}, {50}, {30}, {20}};
std::sort(std::begin(ms), std::end(ms), std::greater<MyStruct>{});
```

This fails to compile because no suitable `operator>` will be found. That's because `std::greater` relies upon [ADL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8111677/241631) to find the operator overload, and ADL searches in associated namespaces. `std::rel_ops` is not an associated namespace for `MyStruct`. You can get everything to work by adding a using declaration to the same namespace as `MyStruct` so that the relevant `operator>` will be found.

```
using std::rel_ops::operator>;
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba63a8b1bcd7250d)

But this is ugly, and not a viable solution in general, so forget about `std::rel_ops` and use [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/utility/operators.htm) as [Barry suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33177112/241631).

Comment: Why do you think its ugly? it does exactly what it should do.

Comment: @Surt It's a matter of opinion of course, but if you wanted the other equality operators as well, then you'd need 4 using declarations. With Boost.Operators, you simply derive from `boost::totally_ordered` (after defining an `operator==` also for your type).

Comment: Well I like your solution as it doesn't need 3rd party includes.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to do it this way:

```
std::vector<MyStruct> v{...};

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const MyStruct& lhs, const MyStruct& rhs){
    using namespace std::rel_ops;
    return lhs > rhs;
});
```

Although `std::rel_ops` is pretty lame. It's easier to use [`boost::less_than_comparable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/utility/operators.htm#less_than_comparable1), in which you just add the operators directly into `MyStruct`:

```
struct MyStruct 
    : boost::less_than_comparable<MyStruct> // <== adds operator>,
                                            //          operator>=, 
                                            //      and operator<=
{
    MyStruct(int i) : field(i) { }
    int field;

    bool operator<(const MyStruct& rhs) const {
        return field < rhs.field;
    }
};
```

And then you can sort it the obvious way:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<MyStruct>());
```

Answer (score 0):

std::rel_ops generate the other comparisons from `==` and `<` so you first need to define at least `<`

```
bool operator<(const MyStruct & lhs, const MyStruct & rhs) {
    return lhs.field < rhs.field;
}
```

Now rel_ops generate `>` so now you can use `std::greater` in `std::sort`

```
std::sort(begin(myVector), end(myVector), std::greater<MyStruct>());
```

Comment: I have already  defined operator < but I got error C2676 from std::greater

Comment: Your `<` has only one parameter, and `std::greater` demands two, further yours is a class member that is not accessible by `std::greater`.

Comment: There's no need to have non-member `operator<`, the member version the OP defined is sufficient. The problem lies with ADL not finding the `operator>` defined within `namespace rel_ops`.

Comment: @Praetorian, yes I can see that from your answer :) now I wonder why.