# Why is ADL not working with Boost.Range?

Tags: c++, boost, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup, boost-range

Considering:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

int main() {
    auto range = boost::irange(1, 4);
    assert(boost::find(range, 4) == end(range));
}
```

[<kbd>Live Clang demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32f4c4502e37d526) 
[<kbd>Live GCC demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d80b41124d9f5ba)

this gives:

> main.cpp:8:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'end'

Considering that if you write `using boost::end;` it [works just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fcfc3c865852af02), which implies that `boost::end` is visible:

Why is ADL not working and finding `boost::end` in the expression `end(range)`? And if it's intentional, what's the rationale behind it?

---

To be clear, the expected result would be similar to what happens in [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a18af912213ca7b8) using `std::find_if` and unqualified `end(vec)`.

Comment: Maybe post the contrasting: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a18af912213ca7b8 so people get why the expectation exists

Comment: Note that in both your code and in the example from @sehe, you can also do an unqualified `find(range, 4)` and `find(begin(v), end(v), 4)` respectively. This is not recommended though, unless you intend to have a customized `find` algorithm depending on the type passed to it.

Comment: @sehe but [there is](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/722a644989abfc4c) (`any_of_equal` is `any_of` with predicate testing for equality to the value)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94433/discussion-between-sehe-and-templaterex).

Comment: @TemplateRex Summary: I didn't know B::Algorithms came with Range support :) This is pretty sweet: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f46da76f94aa2934

Comment: @sehe that example has a bug: 4 is not a prime! Instead of `max(2, n/2)`, the proper bound for the division loop is `floor(sqrt(n)) + 1`. (the bug is that `any_of` on an empty range returns `true`) Also: `!any_of == none_of`: see [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/804df168edfabc4b)

Comment: @TemplateRex LOL! I misread the assertion - not seeing it was inverted. Ugh. Well, the point was the way to do `any_of`, not primality testing :) Thanks for the thoughtful fixed version though!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [`boost/range/end.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/boost/range/end.hpp) they explicitly block ADL by putting `end` in a `range_adl_barrier` namespace, then `using namespace range_adl_barrier;` to bring it into the `boost` namespace.

As `end` is not actually from `::boost`, but rather from `::boost::range_adl_barrier`, it is not found by ADL.

Their reasoning is described in [`boost/range/begin.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/boost/range/begin.hpp):

> // Use a ADL namespace barrier to avoid ambiguity with other unqualified
>   // calls. This is particularly important with C++0x encouraging
>   // unqualified calls to begin/end.

no examples are given of where this causes a problem, so I can only theorize what they are talking about.

Here is an example I have invented of how ADL can cause ambiguity:

```
namespace foo {
  template<class T>
  void begin(T const&) {}
}

namespace bar {
  template<class T>
  void begin(T const&) {}

  struct bar_type {};
}

int main() {
  using foo::begin;
  begin( bar::bar_type{} );
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e203cd540c5c13cd).  Both `foo::begin` and `bar::begin` are equally valid functions to call for the `begin( bar::bar_type{} )` in that context.

This could be what they are talking about.  Their `boost::begin` and `std::begin` might be equally valid in a context where you have `using std::begin` on a type from `boost`.  By putting it in a sub-namespace of `boost`, `std::begin` gets called (and works on ranges, naturally).

If the `begin` in the namespace `boost` had been less generic, it would be preferred, but that isn't how they wrote it.

Comment: @Ven because the reason behind the ADL-blocking namespace (which is identical for the two) is only found in begin.hpp, not end.hpp.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the reasoning. What ambiguity is it trying to avoid?

Comment: @Jefffrey [Maybe this one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e203cd540c5c13cd)?

Comment: @Yakk see my answer for range/container interference from unqualified begin/end

Answer (score 15):

### Historical background

The underlying reason is discussed in this [**closed Boost ticket**](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8571)

> With the following code, compiler will complain that no begin/end is
>   found for "`range_2`" which is integer range. I guess that integer range
>   is missing ADL compatibility ?

```
#include <vector>

#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;

    auto range_1 = boost::make_iterator_range(v);
    auto range_2 = boost::irange(0, 1); 

    begin(range_1); // found by ADL
      end(range_1); // found by ADL
    begin(range_2); // not found by ADL
      end(range_2); // not found by ADL

    return 0;
}
```

---

> `boost::begin()` and `boost::end()` are not meant to be found by ADL. In
>   fact, Boost.Range specifically takes precautions to prevent
>   `boost::begin()` and `boost::end()` from being found by ADL, by declaring
>   them in the `namespace boost::range_adl_barrier` and then exporting them
>   into the `namespace boost` from there. (This technique is called an "ADL
>   barrier").
>
> In the case of your `range_1`, the reason unqualified `begin()` and `end()`
>   calls work is because ADL looks not only at the namespace a template
>   was declared in, but the namespaces the template arguments were
>   declared in as well. In this case, the type of `range_1` is
>   `boost::iterator_range<std::vector<int>::iterator>`. The template
>   argument is in `namespace std` (on most implementations), so ADL finds
>   `std::begin()` and `std::end()` (which, unlike `boost::begin()` and
>   `boost::end()`, do not use an ADL barrier to prevent being found by
>   ADL).
>
> To get your code to compile, simply add "`using boost::begin;`" and
>   "`using boost::end;`", or explicitly qualify your `begin()/end()` calls
>   with "`boost::`".

### Extended code example illustrating the dangers of ADL

The danger of ADL from unqualified calls to `begin` and `end` is two-fold:

1. **the set of associated namespaces can be much larger than one expects**. E.g. in `begin(x)`, if `x` has (possibly defaulted!) template parameters, or hidden base classes in its implementation, the associated namespaces of the template parameters and of its base classes are also considered by ADL. Each of those associated namespace can lead to many overloads of `begin` and `end` being pulled in during argument dependent lookup.
2. **unconstrained templates cannot be distinguished during overload resolution**. E.g. in `namespace std`, the `begin` and `end` function templates are not separately overloaded for each container, or otherwise constrained on the signature of the container being supplied. When another namespace (such as `boost`) also supplies similarly unconstrained function templates, overload resolution will consider both an equal match, and an error occurs.

The following code samples illustrate the above points.

**A small container library**

The first ingredient is to have a container class template, nicely wrapped in its own namespace, with an iterator that derives from `std::iterator`, and with generic and unconstrained function templates `begin` and `end`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

namespace C {

template<class T, int N>
struct Container
{
    T data[N];
    using value_type = T;

    struct Iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T>
    {
        T* value;
        Iterator(T* v) : value{v} {}
        operator T*() { return value; }
        auto& operator++() { ++value; return *this; }
    };

    auto begin() { return Iterator{data}; }
    auto end() { return Iterator{data+N}; }
};

template<class Cont>
auto begin(Cont& c) -> decltype(c.begin()) { return c.begin(); }

template<class Cont>
auto end(Cont& c) -> decltype(c.end()) { return c.end(); }

}   // C
```

**A small range library**

The second ingredient is to have a range library, also wrapped in its own namespace, with another set of unconstrained function templates `begin` and `end`.

```
namespace R {

template<class It>
struct IteratorRange
{
    It first, second;

    auto begin() { return first; }
    auto end() { return second; }
};

template<class It>
auto make_range(It first, It last)
    -> IteratorRange<It>
{
    return { first, last };    
}

template<class Rng>
auto begin(Rng& rng) -> decltype(rng.begin()) { return rng.begin(); }

template<class Rng>
auto end(Rng& rng) -> decltype(rng.end()) { return rng.end(); }

} // R
```

**Overload resolution ambiguity through ADL**

Trouble begins when one tries to make an iterator range into a container, while iterating with unqualified `begin` and `end`:

```
int main() 
{
    C::Container<int, 4> arr = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }};
    auto rng = R::make_range(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    for (auto it = begin(rng), e = end(rng); it != e; ++it)
        std::cout << *it;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12fe7c19551b032f)

**Argument-dependent name lookup on `rng` will find 3 overloads for both `begin` and `end`**: from `namespace R` (because `rng` lives there), from `namespace C` (because the `rng` template parameter `Container<int, 4>::Iterator` lives there), and from `namespace std` (because the iterator is derived from `std::iterator`). **Overload resolution will then consider all 3 overloads an equal match** and this results in a hard error.

Boost solves this by putting `boost::begin` and `boost::end` in an inner namespace and pulling them into the enclosing `boost` namespace by using directives. An alternative, and IMO more direct way, would be **to ADL-protect the types** (not the functions), so in this case, the `Container` and `IteratorRange` class templates.

[**Live Example With ADL barriers**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e0771f6e61fc3ad)

### Protecting your own code may not be enough

Funny enough, ADL-protecting `Container` and `IteratorRange` would -in this particular case- be enough to let the above code run without error because `std::begin` and `std::end` would be called because `std::iterator` is not ADL-protected. **This is very surprising and fragile**. E.g. if the implementation of `C::Container::Iterator` no longer derives from `std::iterator`, the code would stop compiling. It is therefore preferable to use qualified calls `R::begin` and `R::end` on any range from `namespace R` in order to be protected from such underhanded name-hijacking.

Note also that the range-for used to have the above semantics (doing ADL with at least `std` as an associated namespace). This was discussed in [**N3257**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3257.pdf) which led to semantic changes in range-for. The current range-for first looks for member functions `begin` and `end`, so that `std::begin` and `std::end` will not be considered, regardless of ADL-barriers and inheritance from `std::iterator`.

```
int main() 
{
    C::Container<int, 4> arr = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }};
    auto rng = R::make_range(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    for (auto e : rng)
        std::cout << e;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6eacf9a825e737d0)

Comment: Very nice article. Oops. Answer :) The samples are very much on point.

Comment: @sehe tnx for the generous bounty!

Answer (score 6):

That's because `boost::end` is [inside an ADL barrier](https://github.com/boostorg/range/blob/develop/include/boost/range/detail/end.hpp#L74), which is then [pulled in `boost` at the end of the file](https://github.com/boostorg/range/blob/78a8f5bf3d6fccc4038a86884c9c56dbc0e8e1e0/include/boost/range/end.hpp#L124).

However, from [cppreference's page on ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (sorry, I don't have a C++ draft handy):

> 1) using-directives in the associated namespaces are ignored

That prevents it from being included in ADL.