# std::map does not accept my operator<

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11

I have a map with a more or less custom Key-Type (`Point2f` from `OpenCV`) and thus need to write my own `operator<`. Except, my `operator<` doesn't get accepted.

Creation of the Map/Accessing an element by key:

```
using namespace cv;
void foo()
{
    map<Point2f, double> properties;

    properties[Point2f(0, 0)] = 0;
}
```

and this is my operator:

```
using namespace cv;
bool operator<(Point2f lhs, Point2f rhs)
{
    return lhs.x == rhs.x ? lhs.y < rhs.y : lhs.x < rhs.x;
}
```

but when I try to set a value of the map using a key like above, my compiler gives me

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_function.h|235|error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const cv::Point_<float>’ and ‘const cv::Point_<float>’)|
```

(gcc, IDE Code::Blocks)

I already tried

- specifying the type exactly (`cv::Point_<float>`)
- putting the operator directly above the function calling it
- using const, reference or const reference for the variables passed to the operator instead of values

Nothing worked, the error keeps coming. Why does it appear and what do I need to change to make it work?

Comment: Where is your `operator<` declared in relation to this code?

Comment: You need to indicate what parts of your code snippets are within the `cv` namespace, I think the problem is you have your `operator<` defined outside of the namespace, and ADL is not able to find it.

Comment: @NathanOliver First I tried it with the operator< declared in a header file included in the source file using the map. When that didn't work I just moved the definition above the function using the map. Still didn't work.

Comment: @Praetorian I imported both namespaces in all my files (with using namespace std/cv) and it still does not work (I know that is not good practice, but this is just a small project).

Comment: @captain It works here with a made-up `Point2f` class and everything you've described in your post: http://ideone.com/dvCX1r  --  So it is something that you're not telling us, or that `Point2f` class has something internal that is throwing the code off.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for taking the time to create an example, something the OP should've done himself! The problem with it is that your `Point2f` is not within the `cv` namespace.

Comment: @Praetorian Was my first question on this board, but I will remember that. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapting the example posted in the comments, so that the mock `Point2f` class is within the `cv` namespace, as the original is, reproduces the error.

```
namespace cv
{
struct Point2f
{
    int x, y;
    Point2f(int v1, int v2) : x(v1), y(v2) {}
};
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/281b7cb8ff35580c)

Adding a using directive following the definition above makes no difference because `using namespace cv` means *bring everything under the `cv` namespace into the current scope*, not *everything that follows automatically gets added to the `cv` namespace*.

Define your `operator<` as follows so that [ADL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8111677/241631) is able to find it.

```
namespace cv
{
bool operator<(Point2f const& lhs, Point2f const& rhs) // pass by reference is not necessary
                                                       // but might as well
{
    std::cout << "calling custom operator <\n";
    return lhs.x == rhs.x ? lhs.y < rhs.y : lhs.x < rhs.x;
}
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/855acc5b131f3ab4)

---

Another option, to avoid adding operator overloads to someone else's namespace, is to define a comparator for `Point2f` objects.

```
struct Point2fLess
{
    bool operator()(Point2f const&lhs, Point2f const& rhs) const
    {
        std::cout << "calling custom operator <\n";
        return lhs.x == rhs.x ? lhs.y < rhs.y : lhs.x < rhs.x;
    }
};
```

Now define your `map` as

```
std::map<Point2f, double, Point2fLess> properties;
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc2713a9a6ab1b87)

Comment: Now I understand my mistake! Thanks, great answer!