# Are name spaces required for free functions in the STL?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm playing around with my coding style.  I used to explicitly prefix every library call with `std::` but I'm switching over to using declarations like this:

```
using std::count;
using std::vector;
```

One thing I've noticed over the past few days is that sometimes if I forget a using declaration -- `using std::vector;` is a good example -- I get reams of compiler errors.  However, if I neglect to namespace delcare an algorithm such as `using std::count;` my code compiles just fine.

Does this have to do with the difference with classes and free functions?  On all the reference sites, both `count(first, last, value)` and `vector` are prefixed with `std::` so I would expect them to behave the same.

Or does it have to do with other functions in the global namespace?  I notice `std::max` also seems to require a namespace declaration, perhaps it defined in a default-included Apple/glibc/LLVM file and thus there is a conflict if I used it sans namespace declaration?

I am using Apple LLVM 7.0.2. on El Capitan.

**EDIT: Show us the code**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using std::count;
using std::vector;

int main() {
    vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    return count(begin(v), end(v), 3);
}
```

Comment: To give you a better answer, I'd like to see some code.

Comment: The magic word...acronym...entity...thingy... to search for is [*ADL*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Comment: It has to do with the code that you haven't shown. Post the smallest example you can come up with that compiles and shows what you're talking about.

Comment: @T.C. - _ADL_ isn't a word. <g>

Comment: If we're being pedantic, "ADL" is an *initialism*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8111677/1171191

Comment: @Brian We're programmers. We're *always* being pedantic.

Comment: @Brian I think "thingy" is good enough ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As T.C. (almost) said, the magic incantation is ADL, which stands for "argument-dependent lookup". When a function is called with an argument whose type is defined in a namespace, the compiler looks for the function in that same namespace. Makes, sense, right?

Comment: Got it.  Is there any way to disable ADL in LLVM?  Or at least visualize the lookup process?

Comment: @racarate - it's been less than a minute since I posted my answer, and less than 15 minutes since you posted the code that led to it. It's way too soon to accept it; someone else might post something that's absolutely brilliant and leads you into unforeseen depths of understanding.

Comment: But you answered my question.  I thought maybe free functions did not require namespace...-ing...  but now I know in fact they do UNLESS their arguments happen to be in the same namespace.  Your succinct answer indeed led me into unforeseen depths of understanding.