# Why don't I need std:: in front of move with strings?

Tags: c++, string, c++14, move-semantics, argument-dependent-lookup

I'm pretty confused about this code working:

```
#include <string>

int main() {
    int test1 = 0;
    std::string test2;

    std::move(test1);
    // move(test1);
    move(test2);

    return 0;
}
```

I did not put `using namespace std` anywhere, nor `using std::move`. And the weirdest thing in that, it only work with `std::string`! If I uncomment the commented line, it does not compile!

Can someone explain what's happening here? Thanks!

[Live example on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84e707bddbdfdb56)

Comment: It's argument-dependent lookup.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8111677/10077

Comment: I suspected that, but I don't understand the mechanism why I can omit the namespace name.