# Importing a single class into a namespace appears to require that there be no function name collisions between the namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, ambiguous

The following code (surprisingly?) does not compile with either `g++` or `clang++` due to ambiguous calls to `BuildStream` when instantiating `bar::BuildStream` with `bar::Rectangle` as an input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

namespace foo {

struct Rectangle { double height, width; };
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Rectangle& a) { return os; }

inline void BuildStream(std::ostringstream& os) { }

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void BuildStream
(std::ostringstream& os, const T& item, const Args& ...args) {
  os << item;
  BuildStream(os, args...);
}

} // namespace foo

namespace bar {

inline void BuildStream(std::ostringstream& os) { }

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void BuildStream
(std::ostringstream& os, const T& item, const Args& ...args) {
  os << item;
  BuildStream(os, args...);
}

using Rectangle = foo::Rectangle;

} // namespace bar

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::ostringstream os;
  bar::BuildStream(os, 1, 2);
  bar::BuildStream(os, bar::Rectangle(), bar::Rectangle());
  return 0;
}
```

The ambiguity would seem to imply that, generally speaking, if a class is imported from namespace `foo` into namespace `bar`, then care must be taken to ensure that no functions in `bar` have names equal to functions in `foo`. This clearly throws a wrench in some of the benefits of namespaces; is there a more nuanced approach to avoiding such ambiguities?

The context is `foo` being the namespace of a large library and `bar` being a consumer project's namespace (and this problem showed up in practice).

Comment: You will get the same error if you: 1. Remove the "using", 2. Pass "foo::Rectangle" from main. This is due to [argument-dependent lookup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup). Also explicitly invoking bar::BuildStream() from the template function will fix the compilation error.

Comment: Thank you for the link to argument-dependent lookup; that is the right nuanced discussion for explaining this (somewhat unfortunate) behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is with argument-dependent lookup.  `bar::Rectangle` is actually a `foo::Rectangle`, so the call to `BuildStream(os,args...)` needs to check in `foo's` namespace as well for overloads.

Care does need to be taken.  You can avoid the ambiguity by qualifying the call:

```
  template<typename T, typename... Args>
  void BuildStream(std::ostringstream& os, const T& item, const Args& ...args)
  {
    os << item;
    bar::BuildStream(os, args...); // qualified
  }
```

Comment: This explains why it happens but doesn't tell OP how to get around the ambiguity.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Agreed.  I added more to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was definitely aware of how to fix it; what I was looking for was a concise explanation, and argument-dependent lookup is it!