# How can this code cause ambiguity between NS1::format and NS3::format?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Is format imported because it is using imported Object class? 
But with the same logic, a class is not imported if it uses imported Object class.

```
namespace NS1  {
    class Object { /* ... */ };
    int format(const Object&) { std::cout << "NS1"; }
    namespace NS2  {
        class Object { /* ... */ };
        int format(const Object&) { std::cout << "NS2"; }
    }
}

namespace NS3  {
    using NS1::Object;
    int format(const Object&) { std::cout << "NS3"; }
}

namespace  {  using namespace NS3;  }

void fun(Object b, int i)  {  int i1 = format(b);  }

int main()  {
    Object b;
    fun(b, 0);
}
```

Comment: do you get any error? What have you tried to solve it yourself? Have you read [ask]? (me too have questions)

Comment: Probably because of [Argument Dependent Lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a look at the error message that GCC produces:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void fun(NS1::Object, int)’:
test.cpp:19:48: error: call of overloaded ‘format(NS1::Object&)’ is ambiguous
 void fun(Object b, int i)  {  int i1 = format(b);  }
                                                ^
test.cpp:19:48: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:14:5: note: int NS3::format(const NS1::Object&)
 int format(const Object&) { std::cout << "NS3"; }
     ^
test.cpp:5:5: note: int NS1::format(const NS1::Object&)
 int format(const Object&) { std::cout << "NS1"; }
     ^
```

The ambiguity arises because of [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl):

> Argument-dependent lookup, also known as ADL, or Koenig lookup, is the set of rules for looking up the unqualified function names in function-call expressions, including implicit function calls to overloaded operators. **These function names are looked up in the namespaces of their arguments in addition to the scopes and namespaces considered by the usual unqualified name lookup.**

In your case, you are trying to call `format(b)` where `b` is a `NS1::Object`.

- The function `int NS3::format(const NS1::Object&)` is considered because you pulled in that namespace.
- The function `int NS1::format(const NS1::Object&)` is considered because of ADL: The parameter is from namespace `NS1`, so the matching function from `NS1` will be considered as well.
- Both functions have the exact same signature and are hence ambiguous.

It's worth reading [What is "Argument-Dependent Lookup" (aka ADL, or "Koenig Lookup")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup) as well.

Comment: Thanx a lot, that is worth the knowledge

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, you may go ahead and accept the answer. It not, please let me know.