# Broken bitwise-or operator in a Qt project

Tags: c++, qt

I just recently added a QLabel to a ui form in a Qt project, set its text alignment to a custom value, and was then surprised to find that the auto-generated code for the ui class caused a compiler error in MSVC:

> ui_projectwidget.h:109:
>   error: C2664: 'void
>   QLabel::setAlignment(Qt::Alignment)' : cannot convert argument 1 from
>   'int' to 'Qt::Alignment'

`Qt::Alignment` is a flag to indicate left/right/center/etc. text justification.  The offending line in ui_projectwidget.h is:

```
componentName->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignTop);
```

In this project, I overload `operator |` for a scoped enum, `MIBC::ItemType`, that is unrelated to Qt components:

```
using FlagType = int64_t;
enum class ItemType: FlagType {
      type1, type2, etc
}

using Ty = std::underlying_type_t<MIBC::ItemType>;

inline MIBC::ItemType operator| (MIBC::ItemType lhs, MIBC::ItemType rhs) {
    return static_cast<MIBC::ItemType>(static_cast<Ty>(lhs) | static_cast<Ty>(rhs));
}
```

I was able to fix the compiler error by adding another overload for `operator |` for Qt::AlignmentFlag:

```
inline Qt::AlignmentFlag operator|(Qt::AlignmentFlag lhs, Qt::AlignmentFlag rhs) {
    return static_cast<Qt::AlignmentFlag>(static_cast<int>(lhs) | static_cast<int>(rhs));
}
```

Even though I've "fixed" the problem, I still don't understand it.  What broke the default `operator |` such that it no longer accepts `Qt::AlignmentFlag`?  Should I restructure my scoped enum in some way that it doesn't interfere with other bitwise-or operators?

Comment: "The QFlags class provides a type-safe way of storing OR-combinations of enum values. More..."  source: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qflags.html  Including an example and fix that looks very similar to your problem.

Comment: Without a complete program, it's hard to tell.  But it looks like you're in a scope where your definition is hiding Qt's `operator|` (which is in the global namespace).  Note also that Qt gives you some macros to help you define your own flags combinator more easily if you want.

Comment: @RichardCritten I wish I had discovered `QFlags` about 20,000 lines of code sooner...

Comment: @TobySpeight That was the problem indeed.  Adding `using ::operator|;` fixed the problem.

Comment: You haven't fixed the problem, you've plastered over it. You must create a minimal test case that reproduces the issue, and fix your question to include it. Everything must fit into a single `main.cpp` that you should include verbatim, and you must remove everything that doesn't demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you declared the operator in the global namespace, breaking the [argument dependent lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8111677/1329652). Instead, you should have put it in the namespace of its arguments, and let ADL pick it up.

Comment: Yes, moving my custom overloads to the global namespace works as well.  I don't think my original question is salvageable at this point; my problem really had nothing to do with Qt or scoped enums specifically.  I can't seem to find a SO question that specifically addresses this problem, so I may just repost a new question.