# Function from one library matched to template from another library

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, spdlog

I'm working on a C++ project that uses two different libraries: [spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog) for logging, and [mutils-serialization](https://github.com/mpmilano/mutils-serialization) for serializing objects to bytes (for sending over the network). Both libraries use namespaces properly, but when I attempt to write a program that uses both of them at the same time, my compiler (g++ 6.2) gives me nonsensical errors that seem to indicate it is attempting to instantiate a function template from the spdlog library by using the definition of a function template from the mutils library.

Here's my simple test program:

```
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
#include <spdlog/fmt/ostr.h>
#include "TestSerializableObject.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto global_logger = spdlog::rotating_logger_mt("global_logger", "log", 1024 * 1024 * 500, 3);
    global_logger->set_pattern("[%H:%M:%S.%e] [%l] %v");
    global_logger->set_level(spdlog::level::trace);

    std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> logger(spdlog::get("global_logger"));

    auto message = std::make_shared<messaging::TestSerializableObject>(
        1, 2, "A message!");

    logger->trace("Received a message: {}", *message);
}
```

`TestSerializableObject` is a simple class that implements `mutils::ByteRepresentable` (the interface that enables serialization and pulls in the mutils-serialization library), and provides an `operator<<` (which is required for spdlog to be able to log it). I can post the code for it if necessary.

When I compile this with `g++ -std=c++14 -I"./src" -I"./libraries" -I"./libraries/mutils/" -L"./libraries/" -O0 -g3 -Wall "src/LibraryCollisionTest.cpp"`, I get this long, ugly error (don't worry, I'll help you parse it):

```
In file included from ./libraries/mutils/mutils.hpp:3:0,
                 from ./libraries/mutils-serialization/SerializationSupport.hpp:2,
                 from src/TestSerializableObject.h:10,
                 from src/LibraryCollisionTest.cpp:10:
./libraries/mutils/args-finder.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct mutils::function_traits<messaging::TestSerializableObject>’:
./libraries/mutils/args-finder.hpp:75:41:   required from ‘auto mutils::convert(F) [with F = messaging::TestSerializableObject; ignore = void]’
./libraries/spdlog/fmt/bundled/format.h:1276:46:   required from ‘struct fmt::internal::ConvertToInt<messaging::TestSerializableObject>’
./libraries/spdlog/fmt/bundled/format.h:1485:5:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T> fmt::internal::MakeValue<Formatter>::MakeValue(const T&, typename fmt::internal::EnableIf<fmt::internal::Not<fmt::internal::ConvertToInt<T>::value>::value, int>::type) [with T = messaging::TestSerializableObject]’
./libraries/spdlog/fmt/bundled/format.h:2465:12:   required from ‘static fmt::internal::Value fmt::internal::ArgArray<N, true>::make(const T&) [with Formatter = fmt::BasicFormatter<char>; T = messaging::TestSerializableObject; unsigned int N = 1u]’
./libraries/spdlog/fmt/bundled/format.h:2898:5:   required from ‘void fmt::BasicWriter<Char>::write(fmt::BasicCStringRef<CharType>, const Args& ...) [with Args = {messaging::TestSerializableObject}; Char = char]’
./libraries/spdlog/details/logger_impl.h:69:9:   required from ‘void spdlog::logger::log(spdlog::level::level_enum, const char*, const Args& ...) [with Args = {messaging::TestSerializableObject}]’
./libraries/spdlog/details/logger_impl.h:127:5:   required from ‘void spdlog::logger::trace(const char*, const Args& ...) [with Args = {messaging::TestSerializableObject}]’
src/LibraryCollisionTest.cpp:21:53:   required from here
./libraries/mutils/args-finder.hpp:12:37: error: ‘operator()’ is not a member of ‘messaging::TestSerializableObject’
   : public function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())>
                                     ^~
./libraries/mutils/args-finder.hpp: In instantiation of ‘auto mutils::convert(F) [with F = messaging::TestSerializableObject; ignore = void]’:
./libraries/spdlog/fmt/bundled/format.h:1276:46:   required from ‘struct fmt::internal::ConvertToInt<messaging::TestSerializableObject>’
./libraries/spdlog/fmt/bundled/format.h:1485:5:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T> fmt::internal::MakeValue<Formatter>::MakeValue(const T&, typename fmt::internal::EnableIf<fmt::internal::Not<fmt::internal::ConvertToInt<T>::value>::value, int>::type) [with T = messaging::TestSerializableObject]’
./libraries/spdlog/fmt/bundled/format.h:2465:12:   required from ‘static fmt::internal::Value fmt::internal::ArgArray<N, true>::make(const T&) [with Formatter = fmt::BasicFormatter<char>; T = messaging::TestSerializableObject; unsigned int N = 1u]’
./libraries/spdlog/fmt/bundled/format.h:2898:5:   required from ‘void fmt::BasicWriter<Char>::write(fmt::BasicCStringRef<CharType>, const Args& ...) [with Args = {messaging::TestSerializableObject}; Char = char]’
./libraries/spdlog/details/logger_impl.h:69:9:   required from ‘void spdlog::logger::log(spdlog::level::level_enum, const char*, const Args& ...) [with Args = {messaging::TestSerializableObject}]’
./libraries/spdlog/details/logger_impl.h:127:5:   required from ‘void spdlog::logger::trace(const char*, const Args& ...) [with Args = {messaging::TestSerializableObject}]’
src/LibraryCollisionTest.cpp:21:53:   required from here
./libraries/mutils/args-finder.hpp:75:41: error: ‘as_function’ is not a member of ‘mutils::function_traits<messaging::TestSerializableObject>’
   return function_traits<F>::as_function(f);
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
In file included from ./libraries/spdlog/fmt/fmt.h:21:0,
                 from ./libraries/spdlog/common.h:41,
                 from ./libraries/spdlog/spdlog.h:12,
                 from src/LibraryCollisionTest.cpp:8:
./libraries/spdlog/fmt/bundled/format.h: In instantiation of ‘struct fmt::internal::ConvertToInt<messaging::TestSerializableObject>’:
./libraries/spdlog/fmt/bundled/format.h:1485:5:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T> fmt::internal::MakeValue<Formatter>::MakeValue(const T&, typename fmt::internal::EnableIf<fmt::internal::Not<fmt::internal::ConvertToInt<T>::value>::value, int>::type) [with T = messaging::TestSerializableObject]’
./libraries/spdlog/fmt/bundled/format.h:2465:12:   required from ‘static fmt::internal::Value fmt::internal::ArgArray<N, true>::make(const T&) [with Formatter = fmt::BasicFormatter<char>; T = messaging::TestSerializableObject; unsigned int N = 1u]’
./libraries/spdlog/fmt/bundled/format.h:2898:5:   required from ‘void fmt::BasicWriter<Char>::write(fmt::BasicCStringRef<CharType>, const Args& ...) [with Args = {messaging::TestSerializableObject}; Char = char]’
./libraries/spdlog/details/logger_impl.h:69:9:   required from ‘void spdlog::logger::log(spdlog::level::level_enum, const char*, const Args& ...) [with Args = {messaging::TestSerializableObject}]’
./libraries/spdlog/details/logger_impl.h:127:5:   required from ‘void spdlog::logger::trace(const char*, const Args& ...) [with Args = {messaging::TestSerializableObject}]’
src/LibraryCollisionTest.cpp:21:53:   required from here
./libraries/spdlog/fmt/bundled/format.h:1276:38: warning: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to a void type [-Wpointer-arith]
     enum { enable_conversion = sizeof(convert(get<T>())) == sizeof(Yes) };
```

The key line is here:

```
./libraries/mutils/args-finder.hpp: In instantiation of ‘auto mutils::convert(F) 
 [with F = messaging::TestSerializableObject; ignore = void]’:
./libraries/spdlog/fmt/bundled/format.h:1276:46:   required from ‘struct
 fmt::internal::ConvertToInt<messaging::TestSerializableObject>’
./libraries/spdlog/fmt/bundled/format.h:1485:5:   required by substitution of 
 ‘template<class T> fmt::internal::MakeValue<Formatter>::MakeValue(const
 T&, typename fmt::internal::EnableIf<fmt::internal::Not<
 fmt::internal::ConvertToInt<T>::value>::value, int>::type) [with T =
 messaging::TestSerializableObject]’
```

Somehow, g++ has jumped from expanding a templated function inside the spdlog library, in namespace `fmt::internal`, to a function template in the mutils library, in namespace `mutils`, which is clearly not what the spdlog library intended to do! If I look at line 1276 of `format.h`, it's the one that calls the "convert" function inside this template struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct ConvertToInt
{
    enum { enable_conversion = sizeof(convert(get<T>())) == sizeof(Yes) };
    enum { value = ConvertToIntImpl2<T, enable_conversion>::value };
};
```

A few lines above, sure enough, is the function "convert":

```
template <typename T>
T &get();

Yes &convert(fmt::ULongLong);
No &convert(...);
```

These are all inside the namespace `fmt::internal`, and my IDE agrees that if I want the definition of the function "convert" on line 1276, I should jump to the function "convert" on line 1248. So why does g++ ignore this definition, and instead try to use the definition for `mutils::convert()`, which isn't even in the right namespace?

Note that clang also fails to compile this program, and makes the same mistake, so I don't think that this is a bug in g++.

Comment: A fix was comiited in spdlog (https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/commit/d6b34d7b5c62a0000d96939ad946b85a2274f2bb)

Comment: Thanks @GabiMe! I checked out the new version and it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is definitively a bug in <del>spdlog</del> fmtlib, used internally by spdlog.

The *problem* is described summarily in this FAQ:
[What is “Argument-Dependent Lookup” (aka ADL, or “Koenig Lookup”)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8111677/636019)

Because `messaging::TestSerializableObject` inherits from a type in namespace `mutils`, when `convert` is called unqualified from inside namespace `fmt::internal` with a `TestSerializableObject`, both `fmt::internal::convert` *and* `mutils::convert` are considered in the overload set. Variadic functions always rank last during overload resolution, so the template argument `F` in the latter is a better match than the `...` in the former and `mutils::convert` is chosen.

This is in no way specific to your code or to mutils – any type with a unary function or function template named `convert` in the same namespace or a parent namespace is susceptible to this problem.

The *fix* is to qualify the `convert` call and change the definition of `fmt::internal::ConvertToInt<T>::enable_conversion` from

```
enum { enable_conversion = sizeof(convert(get<T>())) == sizeof(Yes) };
```

to

```
enum { enable_conversion = sizeof(internal::convert(get<T>())) == sizeof(Yes) };
```

In my own code I make a habit of always qualifying all calls to functions inside any `internal`/`detail` namespace, even from code inside that same namespace, unless ADL usage is explicitly intended. (N.b. calls don't need to be *fully* qualified, merely qualified.) I learned this lesson from watching Boost have to deal with this problem the hard way as C++11 was emerging.

Comment: Or move the helpers into the trait class as static member functions. There's  no ADL if the name resolves to a class member. One can also parenthesize `convert`, although that's probably too subtle.

Comment: @T.C. : Right, I thought about mentioning the possibility to parenthesize, but that's one of those things that 90% of C++ developers don't know about. Too subtle indeed.

Comment: As a last resort when includes from separate libraries clash like this: It's sometimes a simple solution to use only one of the two libraries in each of your own cpp files.