# Is there any reason find_if, for_each, count etc. do not require std::?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, std

I have just came across the fact that several algorithms from standard `algorithm` header do not require `std::`.

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> m;
  count(m.begin(), m.end(), 0);
  count_if(m.begin(), m.end(), [](auto){return true;});
  for_each(m.begin(), m.end(), [](auto){});
  find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), [](auto){return true;});
}
```

[Live demo at coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61625f399cc2fc0c)

Is there any specific reason for that? Both `g++` and `clang++` accept the code above.

Comment: Because of ADL, bit its best not to rely on it in case you refactor to use custom containers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things going on here.

First is ADL, or [Argument Dependent Name Lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup).

The functions are being found via ADL.  This is because some of the arguments (namely, the `vector`'s `iterator` type) are located in `std`, so when overload resolution looks for `for_each`, it looks in the usual set of namespaces (root in this case), plus ones determined by the namespaces of its arguments.

The trick is that `vector::iterator` is **not guaranteed** to be a type in `namespace std`.  So your code is not guaranteed to work.  It *may* be a type in `std`, or it could be a raw pointer, or it could be a type in `namespace __std__utility_types`, or anywhere else.

All major compiler libraries have `vector` iterators be not-pointers, and they are in `namespace std`, as the alternative is considered worse.  But the lack of guarantee means you shouldn't rely on it for truly portable code.

Comment: I've ran into the issue that Microsoft's IDEs were "finding" those exact functions through ADL (their  "editor assistant" IntelliSense), but on compile time compiler was failing to use ADL.