# Call of overloaded function is ambiguous although different namespace

Tags: c++, ambiguous

I do understand why the following would be a problem if no namespaces were used. The call would be ambiguous indeed. I thought "using stD::swap;" would define which method to use.

Why does it work for "int" but not a "class"?

```
    #include <memory>

    namespace TEST {

    class Dummy{};

    void swap(Dummy a){};
    void sw(int x){};

    }

    namespace stD {

    void swap(TEST::Dummy a){};
    void sw(int x){};

    class aClass{
    public:
        void F()
        {
            using stD::swap;
            TEST::Dummy x;
            swap(x);
        }

        void I()
        {
            using stD::sw;
            int b = 0;
            sw(b);
        }
    };

    }
```

This is the error message:

```
    ../src/Test.h: In member function ‘void stD::aClass::F()’:
    ../src/Test.h:26:9: error: call of overloaded ‘swap(TEST::Dummy&)’ is ambiguous
       swap(x);
             ^
    ../src/Test.h:26:9: note: candidates are:
    ../src/Test.h:17:6: note: void stD::swap(TEST::Dummy)
     void swap(TEST::Dummy a){};
          ^
    ../src/Test.h:10:6: note: void TEST::swap(TEST::Dummy)
     void swap(Dummy a){};
          ^
```

I thank you very much in advance for an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line is using [argument dependent lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup)

```
TEST::Dummy x;
swap(x);
```

So it will find both `void stD::swap(TEST::Dummy)` as well as `void TEST::swap(TEST::Dummy)` because `x` carries the `TEST::` namespace.

In the latter case `int b = 0;` the variable `b` is not in a namespace, so the only valid function to call would be `stD::sw` due to your `using` statement.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that if `F` were not in `stD`, it would call `TEST::swap`.

Comment: Thanks! This fully answers my question. Now this is clear to me.