# Calling a function inside the namespace of T

Tags: c++, sfinae

Lets say I have an enum in a namespace with some helper functions:

```
namespace MyEnumNamespace
{
    enum MyEnum
    {
        Foo,
        Bar
    };

    MyEnum FromString(std::string);
}
```

And I have a deserialization function that I would like to specialize for all enums using SFINAE (assuming they all have the `FromString` function defined).

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>, T> Deserialize(const MyVariant& variant)
{
    return FromString(variant.AsString());
}
```

How would I call `FromString` without knowing the name of the namespace? All I know is that `T` is in the same namespace as `FromString`.

Comment: Do you have control over how `FromString()`s are defined? If so, you could make them `void FromString(std::string, MyEnum &)` instead, and use argument-dependent lookup to call them.

Comment: This might be related to/covered by [Argument Dependent Lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't use namespaces in c++ metaprogramming in the ways you can use types.

If the snippet from the question is from code you can rewrite, one thing you can do is use a `struct` instead of a `namespace` to encapsulate your `enum`s.

It could look something like this:

```
struct MyEnum {
  enum { Foo, Bar } value;
  static MyEnum FromString(std::string);
}
```

*Self promotion*:

A while ago I wrote a tiny [enum traits library](https://gist.github.com/ivankp/1cb894668c01c56880460969e0e262df) using boost preprocessor macros. It also does conversion to and from string, and may help you with your SFINAE problem.

My solution was to define a trait in parallel with an `enum class`.