# Why does `endl` working fine without namespace `std`?

Tags: c++, namespaces, endl

**Case 1:**

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
   std::cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
      return 0;
}
```

Compiler give an error because `endl` need namespace `std` like `std::endl`.

**case 2:**

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
      endl(std::cout); 
      return 0;
}
```

But, In second case without namespace `std`, `endl` working fine. [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ja4yqnABsowvGhts).

Why does `endl` working fine without namespace `std`?

Comment: ADL I guess.....

Comment: `endl` and `basic_ostream` (which is the type of `std::cout`) are both in `std`, so ADL kicks in. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

Comment: @rsp do you agree on the duplicate? Does it answer your question?

Comment: @YSC I don't.  Duplicates are for duplicate *questions* - this question is not a duplicate of that.  (The *answer* is, but that's different).

Comment: Before I had that badge I could simply vote to close a question as a duplicate. Sometimes, when on doubt, I'd like to get back to that instead of single handedly close the question.

Comment: @YSC: If you are in doubt, don't cast the vote. That applies whether you have a dupehammer or not.

Comment: In fact, ADL also explains why case 1 works, since the first `<<` refers to a `std::operator<<` function.

Comment: @MartinBonner: FWIW SE prefers we consider "whether the question has been answered elsewhere" rather than whether the question is actually the same, though I'm not sure I agree with that and I definitely agree that the wording across the site doesn't support it.

Comment: @YSC : I have just [asked on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368596/should-we-close-as-duplicate-for-answered-by-these-answers-or-only-for-same)  whether this should have been closed as duplicated. I am rather expecting the answer "yes", although that is not my preference.

Comment: @MartinBonner thx, will monitor

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit see above for meta question

Comment: Meta discussion is clear: it should be closed as a duplicate - but this is the one case where closing a question doesn't necessarily mean it was a bad question.