# on the use of std:: before function regex_replace

Tags: c++, regex, stl, std

Either I misuse the `std::` in front of functions, either there is something I do not understand when using the `regex_replace` function.

For example, in the piece of code below (the latter compiles and runs correctly on my machine), I don't understand why the scope specification `std::` before `regex_replace` is not required by my compiler (`g++ -Wall -std=c++11` v. 6.4.0 on cygwin), whereas all other `std::` occurences are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
int main()
{
    std::string myString("myRegexReplaceTest");
    std::cout << myString << std::endl;
    std::cout << regex_replace(myString, std::regex("a|e|i|o|u|y"), "[$&]") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What did I miss ?

Regards,
xflr6.

Edit : As pointed out to me by juanchopanza, the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8111750/10132603), although my question is rised in a very different way... And the answer is much more complete than what I first expected. Thanks.