# Using operators from different namespace through inherited class?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, operator-overloading

How come [the following piece of code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48e8a1c7a96885ef) compiles (and prints `V::operator+`)?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace V {

struct B {};

template<typename T>
auto operator+(T rhs) -> T {
    std::cout << "V::operator+\n";
    return rhs;
}

}

struct A : V::B {};

int main() {
    +A();
}
```

The class `A` is outside of the namespace `V` and inherits from `B`, which is inside `V`. `V` also contains an operator template that could, for example, be used on `B`.

No `operator+` is defined for `A` outside of `V`, and yet it can be called on `A` without any qualification (something like `V::operator+(A())`). Removing the inheritance produces the expected error `'operator+' not defined`.

Why can this operator be used outside of `V` without qualification?

Comment: It's called ADL.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argument-dependent lookup extends to the namespaces of the base classes. [basic.lookup.argdep]/2.2:

> If `T` is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are: the class itself; the class of which it is a member, if any; and its direct and indirect base classes. Its associated namespaces are the innermost enclosing namespaces of its associated classes.

Thus, when the compiler is looking for an `operator+` to apply to type `A`, it also searches in the namespace `V` because `A` has a base class that is a member of `V`.