# Any functions that need the std:: prefix

Tags: c++, object, standards, std

What are all the functions (ex std::cout, std::cin, etc.) that need the std:: when not using namespace std?It would be useful to know so I don’t run into problems, thanks!

Comment: They are pretty much all here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/

Comment: If you are using something from the standard library just use `std::`.

Comment: don't use `using namespace std` and you won't have problems  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: I plan to not use using namespace std, I was just wondering what I would need to use std:: in front of.

Comment: It looks like what you are asking about is [ADL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup).

Comment: `std::cout` and `std::cin` are not functions. They’re objects.

Comment: If you're using anything in the C++ standard library, types and names are in namespace `std`.  There are some exceptions (e.g. macros that derive from C headers) but, unless you use C library facilities you won't often encounter them.    User code (i.e. other than the standard library) cannot place names in `std` without causing undefined behaviour (with a couple of exceptions, such specialising template functions to accept user-defined types, such as `std::swap()`).

Answer (score 1):

The ISO C++ standards specify that "all library entities are defined within namespace std", so you're looking for the entire `libstdc++` namespace. It is provided here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01544.html

Comment: thats actually a pretty good list with the caveat that anything prefixed with an `_` is implementation dependent and not part of the C++ standard

Comment: `libstdc++` is _an_ implementation of the Standard Library. There are more, and the ISO C++ Standard allows implementations to have additional names in `std`.