# Use one namespace or another in function of a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces

I want to use the implementation of `std::pow` (from `cmath`) in some cases, and in other cases, I want to use `myspace::pow`.

```
namespace myspace
{
    template <typename T>
    T pow(T val, unsigned exp)
    {
        if (exp == 0) return 1;
        return val*pow(val,exp-1);
    }
}
```

The different cases are determined by a template parameter.

```
template <typename T>
void myFunction()
{
    auto val = pow(2.1,3);
    /* ... */
}
```

If `T == double`, I want `val` to be calculated with `std::pow`. If `T == mydouble`, I want `val` to be calculated with `myspace::pow`. Now, I have a lot of lines like `auto val = pow(2.1,3);`, and I would like to avoid to check for the type of `T` for each line of code.

```
struct mydouble { /* ... */ };
myFunction<double>(); // uses std::pow
myFunction<mydouble>(); // uses myspace::pow
```

I've been breaking my head over this, but I can't find a solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could check T's type with a constexpr if and std::is_same<T, double>::value.

Comment: @nada ok, I have to edit the question to be more clear. I'd like to avoid checking the type for each command.

Comment: I think you can do it using `std::enable_if`

Comment: Or overload pow for mydouble.

Comment: @MFnx with constexpr if or std::enable_if you're checking types at compile time, so no runtime performance penalty, if that's what you're concerned about.

Comment: @nada Could you give me an example? I don't want to check the type each time I call the pow function.

Comment: What's wrong with normal function overloading? Just write your `pow` as `mydouble pow(mydouble val, unsigned exp) ...` (**do this in the same namespace that `mydouble` is in**) and everything should work perfectly fine.

Comment: @MFnx The type check can be done _inside_ your `pow` implementation with `constexpr if` and/or `std::enable_if`.

Comment: @MFnx As I said, the type is *not* checked each time the pow function is called, with mentioned methods it's checked at compile time.

Comment: You can do something like `using mypow = std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, double::value>, std::pow>::value;` and similar to `mydouble`, then just use `mypow()`.

Comment: Do you know of ADL (argument dependent lookup)?

Comment: @L.F. no, I'll look that up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "Argument-Dependent Lookup" (aka ADL, or "Koenig Lookup")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup)

Comment: Someone could provide an answer with enable_if?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several solutions I could suggest.

---

#### Class Dispatcher (C++11)

Just implement a *functor* which picks the correct implementation in accordance with its templated type:

```
template <typename T>
struct PowerAdapter {
  auto operator()(const T& arg, const T& exp) const {
    return std::pow(arg, exp);
  }
};

template <>
struct PowerAdapter<myspace::MyDouble> {
  auto operator()(const myspace::MyDouble& arg, unsigned exp) const {
    return myspace::pow(arg, exp);
  } 
};
```

And you can use it as follows:

```
template <typename T>
void myFunction(const T& t) {
  using Pow = PowerAdapter<T>;

  auto val = Pow{}(t, t);
  // ...
}
```

[Complete Code Example](https://godbolt.org/z/9TBV8i)

---

#### Argument-Dependent Lookup (C++98)

If your class `MyDouble` is in the same namespace of your `pow` then you can just use this C++ rule:

> [...] **function names are looked up in the namespaces of their arguments** in addition to the scopes and namespaces considered by the usual unqualified name lookup.

So the code:

```
template <typename T>
void myFunction(const T& t) {
  pow(t, 12);
}
```

will select the proper `pow` in accordance with the namespace of `T`.
Note that, in case of `double`, you want to select the `pow` from `math.h` in the *global namespace* (unqualified name lookup).

[Complete Code Example](https://godbolt.org/z/A19cCi)

*I personally don't like this approach because it hides the selection mechanism and it's more difficult to extend.*

---

#### `if constexpr` (C++17)

You can pick a proper branch at compile time.
Wrap your select logic into a proper function (or functor). Something like:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto PowerAdapter(const T& val, const U& exp) {
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, myspace::MyDouble>) {
    return myspace::pow(val, exp);
  } else {
    return std::pow(val, exp);
  }
}
```

[Complete Code Example](https://godbolt.org/z/DEVhAU)

Answer (score 0):

Using [Argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) you can achieve this easily

```
namespace ns
{
    template <typename T>
    auto pow(T val, unsigned exp)
    {
        using std::pow;
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        return pow(val, exp);
    }
}

struct mydouble
{
    double d;
};

mydouble pow(mydouble val, unsigned exp)
{
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    return val;
}

int main() 
{
    ns::pow(mydouble{ 3.14 }, 2); // runs pow
    ns::pow(4, 2);                // runs std::pow
}
```