# Overloading << operator results in it being ambiguous

Tags: c++

So, I have a question in regards to an error I recently experienced when I tried to overload the << operator.

I have a file, called "structPixels.h" where in I define a struct as follows:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

namespace Eng
{
    /**
     * A structure to represent pixels
     */
    typedef struct Pixel{
        unsigned int x; ///The x-coordinate
        unsigned int y; ///The y-coordinate

        bool operator ==(const Pixel& rhs) const
        {
            return (this->x == rhs.x && this->y == rhs.y);
        };

        bool operator !=(const Pixel& rhs) const
        {
            return (this->x != rhs.x || this->y != rhs.y);
        };

        bool operator <(const Pixel& rhs) const
        {
            return std::tie(this->x, this->y) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y);
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Pixel& p);
    } Pixel;
}//End of namespace Eng

namespace std {
    //Removing the inline does not fix the error. Rather, it fixed another error
    //which I had with duplicate symbols
    inline ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Eng::Pixel &p)
    {
        os << "{" 
        << p.x 
        << "," 
        << p.y 
        << "}";
        return os;
    }
}//End of namespace std
```

However, when I create it and call a cout like so:

```cpp
#include "structPixels.h"

Pixel test = {3, 4};
std::cout << "Test: " << test << std::endl;
```

I get that:

```
error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' and 'Eng::Pixel')

std::cout << "Test: " << test << std::endl;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~
```

EDIT:
From the help below, we moved the operator, such that the code looks like so:

```cpp
namespace Eng
{

    /**
     * A structure to represent pixels
     */
    typedef struct Pixel{
        unsigned int x; ///The x-coordinate
        unsigned int y; ///The y-coordinate

        bool operator ==(const Pixel& rhs) const
        {
            return (this->x == rhs.x && this->y == rhs.y);
        };

        bool operator !=(const Pixel& rhs) const
        {
            return (this->x != rhs.x || this->y != rhs.y);
        };

        bool operator <(const Pixel& rhs) const
        {
            return std::tie(this->x, this->y) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y);
        }
    } Pixel;

    inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Pixel& rhs)
    {
        os << "{" << rhs.x << "," << rhs.y << "}";
        return os;
    }
}//End of namespace Eng
```

This solved the error :)!

Comment: Unless you really want to override '<<', creating a `.toString()` function is much cleaner and is less error prone.

Comment: `namespace std` -- Why are you putting the overload there? Also: `bool operator !=(const Pixel& rhs) const { return !(this == rhs); }` -- no need to rewrite `==` inside out.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - I wanted to avoid saying std::ostream since I have other functions I have within that namespace that is not included in the example above. I try to make it clean :D And you're right with the second part :)

Comment: Polluting the standard namespace is not clean!! Just write `std::`.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Thanks for the input haha :D

Comment: @Tikki: Welcome :P

Comment: Why the `typedef struct Pixel {...} Pixel;`?  This is C++, not C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you cannot add function overloads into `std`.  Doing so is undefined behavior.  What you want to do is put

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Eng::Pixel &p)
{
    os << "{" 
    << p.x 
    << "," 
    << p.y 
    << "}";
    return os;
}
```

inside the `Eng` namespace.  Doing that [allows the code to compile just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36e6d00758a6d2cb).  Having the operator in the namespace also allows for [ADL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup) to work so the operator will be found even if the user doesn't have `using namespace Eng;` in their code.

---

The reason you get am ambiguity from doing what you did is because the compiler finds two different functions.  It finds

```
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Pixel& p);
```

via ADL, and it finds the function you defined in `std`.  Since those functions are in different namespaces they are considered as overloads and since both are equal, you get an ambiguity error.

Comment: Doing as explained, it first complains about 3 parameters, which is quickly resolved by removing Pixel p and replacing p with this. However, this introduces a new error:

error: invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' and 'Eng::Pixel')

Comment: @Tikki Works fine: https://godbolt.org/z/apGXQa Did you check the link Nathan included?

Comment: @Tikki Not sure why, I'd have to see an [mre] in order to tell you.  The solution works just fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36e6d00758a6d2cb)

Comment: I realised a mistake I just made - I acidently put it within the struct of eng. I moved it out of the struct and into the namespace and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Tikki No problem.  Glad to help.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Another side question, although the points have already been awarded; if I remove inline, I get a duplicate symbol error. Do you know why this is such? The file.h is included in two other files: 


duplicate symbol 'Eng::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Eng::Pixel const&)' in:    CMakeFiles/Main.dir/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Main.dir/classHPAMaze.cpp.o

Comment: @Tikki The way C++ works is if you have something defined in header file like a variable or a function, then that definition is copied into every cpp file that includes it.  That means when the linker gets to the code, it sees a bunch of translation units that define the same thing.  The linker can't handle that and you get an error.  When you use `inline` you say *hey, I know this was defined in other translation units but that is okay.  Just toss out all the repeats and just keep one defintion*.

Comment: While it’s definitely not a good idea, it’s okay to add a function to `std` **if** one or more of its arguments is a user-defined type.

Comment: I could marry you all. Thanks again :)

Comment: @PeteBecker No it is not.  [You are explicitly not allowed to do that](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/requirements#namespace.std-7).  Only template specializations can be added.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica -- The current standard says "A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited." [namespace.std]/1. `operator<<` is a template function, so specializing it in `std` is okay. C++20 (i.e., not the standard), which you link to, has essentially the same language in paragraph 2. Paragraph 7, which you linked to, is about **customization points**.

Comment: @PeteBecker A template specialization has the form `template <> return_type function_name<template_params>(function_params)`.  The OP added `return_type function_name(function_params)` which is an overload, not a specialization.  You can't add overloads, only specializations.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica -- that paragraph 7 that you linked to is irrelevant, since it talks about what's **allowed outside of** `std`. The operative language is in paragraph 1, "Unless otherwise specified, the behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std." </snark>

Comment: @PeteBecker It states *Other than in namespace std or in a namespace within namespace std, a program may provide an overload* Which means in namespace `std` or a namespace within it is not allowed to add an overload.  Google: can we add overloads into std namespace and you'll see every answer says you can't.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica -- no, it means that **that paragraph** says that it's okay to write these things outside of `std`. It says nothing about what's allowed in `std`. But, really, why do you insist that this is the operative paragraph, when paragraph 1 **clearly says what you want**? Take a victory when you get it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you've declared two overloads of `operator<<` -- one in `namespace Eng` (the friend declaration in the class) and one in `namespace std`.  The compiler doesn't know which to use.

Generally you should put operator<< overloads (only) in the namespace of the class being output.  You should never put anything into namespace std, as it is undefined as to whether it will work.

Comment: That would explain the symbol linking error I got earlier :)!