# Why does the following templated class member function not compile?

Tags: c++, templates

The following code compiles even though `nonexisting_func()` doesn't exist. The code compiles because it's a member function of a templated class, but the function itself is not compiled because it's not being used in the program, correct? So you could have any syntax errors inside `heapify_down` and the entire code should still compile?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class heap
{
public:
   void heapify_down(std::vector<T> &vec)
   {
      nonexisting_func(vec);
   }
};

int main( ) 
{ 
   heap<int> my_heap;
   return 0;
}
```

If my understanding above is correct, then why does the following code not compile?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class heap
{
public:
   void heapify_down(std::vector<T> &vec)
   {
      a;
      nonexisting_func(vec);
   }
};

int main( ) 
{ 
   heap<int> my_heap;
   return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code gives me the error `error: use of undeclared identifier 'a'`. Why is it trying to compile the `heapify_down()` function now?

Comment: Are you looking for a language-lawyer type answer, or a practical one? This behavior unfortunately tends to be different based on which compiler you use...

Comment: `a;` on its own is nonsense. To declare a variable you need 1) a type. 2) a variable name. 

See something missing?

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's the point of the question. OP is purposefully putting in errors into the function. They are asking why the error comes up even if the function isn't used.

Comment: @Frank Could you provide both answers? I don't quite understand this behavior

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Right. Is `a;` any more nonsense than calling a function that doesn't exist?

Comment: @François Because the program needs to be syntactically valid, regardless of what parts of it are used, of course.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Why is `a;` less syntactically valid than `nonexisting_func(vec);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template code basically has two passes that it goes through.  The first pass just looks at the code and makes sure that it is syntactically correct, and that any non-dependent code is correct.  By non-dependent code, I mean code that does not depend on the template parameter(s).

After that there is a second pass that happens after the template is actually instantiated.  At that point there is no more dependent code as all the template parameters are known and the compiler can exam the code like it would for any non-template code.

In

```
void heapify_down(std::vector<T> &vec)
{
    nonexisting_func(vec);
}
```

The call to `nonexisting_func` depends on `vec` because of [ADL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup) and `vec` depends on `T` so it's compilation is deferred.  It is syntactically correct so it wont have any further checking done until it is instantiated.  If you changed main to

```
int main( ) 
{ 
   std::vector<int> foo;
   heap<int> my_heap;
   my_heap.heapify_down(foo);
   return 0;
}
```

So that `heapify_down` is actually instantiated then you would get a compiler error like

```
main.cpp:22:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nonexisting_func'
      nonexisting_func(vec);
      ^
main.cpp:30:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'heap<int>::heapify_down' requested here
   my_heap.heapify_down(foo);
           ^
1 error generated.
```

You would also get an error using

```
void heapify_down(std::vector<T> &vec)
{
    ::nonexisting_func(vec);
}
```

Because now we are no longer have an unqualified name so ADL is ignored meaning `::nonexisting_func` is no longer a dependent name.

With

```
void heapify_down(std::vector<T> &vec)
{
   a;
   nonexisting_func(vec);
}
```

`a` doesn't depend on `T` so the compiler tries to look it up.  It can't find it, so you get an error.  If you had instead done

```
void heapify_down(std::vector<T> &vec)
{
   this->a;
   nonexisting_func(vec);
}
```

then again you would not get an error until you instantiate the function since `a` now depends on `this` and `this` depends on `T`.

Comment: Question regarding your last sentence. You say that `this` depends on `T`. But isn't `T` is known through `heap<int> my_heap;`?

Comment: @Iamanon `T` is known when you do `heap<int> my_heap;` but before that it is not so the compiler has to wait for the second pass (after you do `heap<int> my_heap;`) before it actually can check what `this` refers to.

Comment: @Iamanon And even then, unless you use `heapify_down` the compiler can defer instantiating and checking it.

Comment: It might be useful to note that `nonexisting_func(vec);` depends on `T` because of ADL, and `::nonexisting_func(vec);` fails to compile

Answer (score 3):

The key point here is that `nonexisting_func(vec);` is going to mean something different depending on what `T` is (since vec is a `vector<T>`).

So in that case, the compiler cannot try to resolve the call to `nonexisting_func()` immediately as it lexes the function, and can only do so when comes the time to instantiate the template (which you never do).

In the case of `a`, since that identifier doesn't depend on anything, the compiler should perform the lookup immediately. I say should because MSVC in particular tends to still delay the lookup until instantiation, even though it shouldn't on paper.

Comment: ahhh that makes sense. I also had tested calling `nonexisting_func()` without an argument that has a template dependency, and in that case, the code failed to compile.

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by "instantiate the template?" Doesn't `heap<int> my_heap;` instantiate the template?

Comment: @lamanon it instantiates the class, meaning all the declarations have to be valid, but   it doesn't instantiate definitions for member functions that you never call. In your first example if you called `my_heap.heapify_down({});` from main, it would fail to compile

Comment: A compiler is not required to perform the lookup immediately.   The standard requires an implementation to issue a diagnostic.   It doesn't stipulate *when* in the process of translating source code that it should issue that diagnostic.

Comment: @Peter The problem is that MSVC does not **ever** issue any diagnostics for non-dependant lookup failure for never instantiated templates.

Comment: @Frank FWIW, GCC and clang do the same thing.  Untill the template code is actually instantiated, the compiler can defer fully checking it.

Comment: @Frank - Quite a few compilers do that since, by the way they work, they don't have information needed to issue a diagnostic until the template is instantiated.   The general rule of thumb is that, if you want to be sure the compiler will issue diagnostics, you write code (e.g. test cases) that implicitly or explicitly instantiates the template with representative template parameters.