# "could not match 'T [S]' against 'std::vector<int>'" for some functions but not others with same parameter list

Tags: c++, templates, types

For a homework assignment, I'm trying to create my own versions of `std::find`, `std::begin`, `std::end`, and `std::size`.

I've written some code that looks like this:

```cpp
#include <vector>

template <typename I, typename T>
I find(const I& beg, const I& end, const T& sought)
    {/* ... */}

template <typename T, size_t S>
T* begin(T (&a)[S])
    {return &a;}

template <typename T, size_t S>
T* end(T (&a)[S])
    {return &a + S;}

template <typename T, size_t S>
constexpr size_t size(T (&)[S])
    {return S;}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {0, 1, 2, 3};

    // ...

    // test not-found case (and `size()`)
    find(begin(vec), end(vec), size(vec));

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

(`size_t` should implicitly convert to `int`)

However when I compile, clang gives off the following error:

```
$ clang++ -o program ./*.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wnon-virtual-dtor
./main.cpp:##:##: error: no matching function for call to 'size'
    find(begin(vec), end(vec), size(vec)
    ^~~~
./main.cpp:##:##: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'T [S]' against 'std::vector<int>'
constexpr size_t size(T (&)[S])
                 ^
1 error generated.
```

What really baffles me is that both `size()` and `begin()`/`end()` have the exact same template structure and parameter list, and yet the former throws a compile error while the latters don't when given the same input.

I don't think the different return type is the issue, since if it was `find()` would be complaining, not `size()`.

So how is `size()` different from the other functions that it would throw this error with the same template structure, parameter list, and input?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I've added the include to the code in my question.

Comment: yes, now I get the same error.

Comment: I think this question can be simplified by removing `find`, `begin`, `end`, and `size`. It's really "why does ADL find `begin` and `end` for a `std::vector` argument, but not `size`?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of your `begin`/`end`/`size` templates match, because they only match for raw arrays (type `T[S]`) and not for the type you are using (`std::vector<T>`).  You only get one error because the calls to `begin` and `end` will match the functions `std::begin` and `std::end`, due to [argument dependent lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup).  There is no `std::size` function (in C++11), so the only possible match for `size` is your `size` function which doesn't match, so you get an error.

Comment: Just to be clear, there is a [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) *now*, but this question is living in the past (`-std=c++11`). If you adjust it to `-std=c++17`, the code in the question works as is.