# C++ method definition does not know about class type

Tags: c++

Why does the compiler complain that returning `Settings` is undefined, while it's perfectly happy accepting it as an argument?

## foo.hpp

```
class Foo {
  public:
     typedef struct{
         int id;
     } Settings;

     Settings GetSettings();
     void SetSettings(Settings settings);
};
```

## foo.cpp

```
// nope
Settings Foo::GetSettings(){
}

// no problem
void Foo::SetSettings(Settings settings){

}
```

Comment: It's because of [argument dependent lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that `Settings` is in the scope of `Foo`, since that's where it's defined.

This compiles just fine:

```
//foo.cpp

Foo::Settings Foo::GetSettings(){
}
```

Inside the class, you don't need to specify that, since the compiler considers all names in the scope of the class.

In this definition,

```
//foo.cpp

void Foo::SetSettings(Settings settings){
}
```

the compiler knows that you are defining a function of `Foo`, so similarly, you don't have to specify the scope that the compiler should look at, for the function argument `Settings`.

It might seem that the compiler should know that `GetSettings` is also a function of `Foo`. This is mostly right, and in fact, this compiles just fine:

```
auto Foo::GetSettings() -> Settings {
}
```

In this case, the compiler knows in which scope to look for the return type, by the time it has to figure it out.

Comment: `the compiler knows that you are defining a function of Foo` - how can that not be said for both methods?

Comment: @terratermatwoa added more explanation.

Comment: Thanks.. Still seems "wrong". The compiler is really guessing that `Settings` is of `Foo::` in the setter function. It could be some other struct..But I guess that's how it is.

Comment: @terratermatwoa the compiler probably could work out that you are defining a method but the standard says its not allowed to, the compiler reads the tokens in order and at the point it reads the `Settings` token it doesn't know that the next tokens will tell it that its the return type of a method in `Foo`

Comment: @terratermatwoa -- when it sees that initial `Settings` the compiler doesn't know that it's compiling a member function of the class `Foo`. It doesn't know that until it sees the `Foo::` that starts the member function name. And it's not allowed to go back; all it can do is complain. So you need to say `Foo::` for **both** `Foo::Settings` and `Foo::GetSettings`; the first one says that the return type is a member of `Foo` and the second one says that the function is a member of `Foo`.