# Why is std::begin accessible unqualifiedly when I include vector?

Tags: c++, header, std, using, qualified-name

I thought that I always need the `std::` qualification for `std::something`, unless I'm `using std::something` or the whole `namespace std`, but it seems that `#include <vector>` makes, for instance, `std::begin` availble as `begin`.

Why is this the case?

```cpp
#include <vector>
int main(){
    int w[3];
    begin(w); // Ok, this doesn't compile, as I'm not `using std::begin` nor `using namespace std`.
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.begin(); // Ok, as this is the member function.
    begin(v); // Why does this compile? What is making this free-function available unqualifiedly?
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup

Comment: [g++, clang++ and msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/zeGc76) all give the same result.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe.  `int w[3];` is a built in type, it does not live a namespace so no ADL. `v` on the other hand is a `std::vector` which lives in `std` and ADL finds `begin` in `std`  for you.