# code doesn't compile with a specific name function

Tags: c++, g++

This piece of code doesn't compile on my computer (EDIT with minimal example):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

template<class PValues>
inline bool equal(PValues it,
                  PValues last,
                  size_t  cols,
                  size_t  rows,

                  size_t offset)
{
  if(std::distance(it,last)<offset)
    return false;

  for(size_t c=0; c<cols; ++c)
    {
      auto p = it + c*rows;
      if(*p != *(p + offset))
        return false;
    }

  return true;
};



int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> vec = {"1","1","1","2","2","2","3","8","8",
                                  "5","5","2","5","5","5","6","8","8",
                                  "3","3","3","4","4","3","9","8","8"};
  std::vector<double> nbs = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

  auto res = equal(vec.data(), vec.data()+9, 3, 9, 1);
}
```

I have the following error :

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of ‘bool std::__equal4(_II1, _II1, _II2, _II2, _BinaryPredicate) [with _II1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; _II2 = long unsigned int; _BinaryPredicate = int]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:1219:38:   required from ‘bool std::equal(_IIter1, _IIter1, _IIter2, _IIter2, _BinaryPredicate) [with _IIter1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; _IIter2 = long unsigned int; _BinaryPredicate = int]’
main.cpp:60:15:   required from ‘size_t remove_duplicates_rows_impl(PValues, PResults, size_t, size_t) [with PValues = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; PResults = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >; size_t = long unsigned int]’
main.cpp:99:32:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:1139:13: error: no type named ‘iterator_category’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<long unsigned int>’
 1139 |       using _Cat2 = typename iterator_traits<_II2>::iterator_category;
      |             ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:1140:13: error: no type named ‘iterator_category’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<long unsigned int>’
 1140 |       using _RAIters = __and_<is_same<_Cat1, _RATag>, is_same<_Cat2, _RATag>>;
      |             ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:1144:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘distance(long unsigned int&, long unsigned int&)’
 1144 |    auto __d2 = std::distance(__first2, __last2);
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:66,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:138:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _InputIterator> constexpr typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type std::distance(_InputIterator, _InputIterator)’
  138 |     distance(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:138:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h: In substitution of ‘template<class _InputIterator> constexpr typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type std::distance(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = long unsigned int]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:1144:29:   required from ‘bool std::__equal4(_II1, _II1, _II2, _II2, _BinaryPredicate) [with _II1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; _II2 = long unsigned int; _BinaryPredicate = int]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:1219:38:   required from ‘bool std::equal(_IIter1, _IIter1, _IIter2, _IIter2, _BinaryPredicate) [with _IIter1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; _IIter2 = long unsigned int; _BinaryPredicate = int]’
main.cpp:60:15:   required from ‘size_t remove_duplicates_rows_impl(PValues, PResults, size_t, size_t) [with PValues = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; PResults = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >; size_t = long unsigned int]’
main.cpp:99:32:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:138:5: error: no type named ‘difference_type’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<long unsigned int>’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of ‘bool std::__equal4(_II1, _II1, _II2, _II2, _BinaryPredicate) [with _II1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; _II2 = long unsigned int; _BinaryPredicate = int]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:1219:38:   required from ‘bool std::equal(_IIter1, _IIter1, _IIter2, _IIter2, _BinaryPredicate) [with _IIter1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; _IIter2 = long unsigned int; _BinaryPredicate = int]’
main.cpp:60:15:   required from ‘size_t remove_duplicates_rows_impl(PValues, PResults, size_t, size_t) [with PValues = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; PResults = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >; size_t = long unsigned int]’
main.cpp:99:32:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:1153:37: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘long unsigned int’)
 1153 |  if (!bool(__binary_pred(*__first1, *__first2)))
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:1153:25: error: ‘__binary_pred’ cannot be used as a function
 1153 |  if (!bool(__binary_pred(*__first1, *__first2)))
```

What seems strange to me is : if I change the name of the function equal to equalx (or equalz, just an example), it compiles. The code doesn't compile on godbolt to, but it compiles on onlinegdb : https://onlinegdb.com/ryM5LK4JP .

My version of g++ :

> g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0

Line use to compile the example :

> g++ -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp

Comment: Argument-dependent lookup is weird.

Comment: The equal function of stl library cause this error. Use ::equal to call your equal function.

Comment: Way too much code, given that the error results from some interaction between your code and a standard header on your system.   You need to cut it down to produce a [mcve].    It's really hard to know, but chances are there is some interaction between the name of your function and a non-standard macro specified in one of the standard header files.

Comment: Ah yes it works ! But I don't understand, I don't use std::equal, and I have no line like "using namespace std" ?

Comment: @Kafka Some relevant info [in this ADL related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change the call to `equal` from `equal(first_v, last_v, cols, rows, 1)` to
`equal(first_v, last_v, cols, rows, size_t(1))`, the code compiles.

The reason the code compiles if you change the name is that there's a standard algorithm named [`std::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal).  This function is looked at in overload resolution because the first two arguments share the `std` namespace with the function, so [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) happens.
`std::equal` may take 5 arguments, all of which are templated, so that will be selected as the best match in overload resolution.  To use your function, there would have to be an implicit conversion from `int` to `size_t`.
By changing the last parameter to `size_t(1)` there's no conversion necessary to call your function, thus that is what is selected in overload resolution.

Comment: ok, I didn't know this behaviour. It's clearer now, thank you.