# Why `std` prefix is not required to call the `lower_bound` function?

Tags: c++, g++, std, lower-bound

Just for curiosity, I found a rather strange exception, that you can use a `lower_bound` function without telling in which namespace it is located. The following code:

```
// main.cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

// The std prefix is required for the vector, but not for the lower_bound, why?
using std::vector;

int main() {
    vector<int> v = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    int index = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 2) - v.begin();
    // prints 2, as expected.
    printf("%d\n", index);
    return 0;
}
```

compiles with `g++ main.cpp` command, `g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0` compiler.

**Question**: does `lower_bound` belong to any namespace? If no, what's the motivation for such design?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

Comment: @Mankarse Makes sense, could accept such answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "Argument-Dependent Lookup" (aka ADL, or "Koenig Lookup")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup)

Comment: Notice that `std::vector::iterator` is not necessary part of `std`, might be `int*`, so, `std::` should be required.

Comment: @RichardCritten yes, it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lower_bound()` is indeed in the `std` namespace, as expected.  The reason you can call it without specifying the `std::` prefix is because of [Argument-Dependent Lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).  You are passing `std::vector` iterators to `lower_bound()`, and those iterator types happen to reside in the `std` namespace in your compiler's implementation of `std::vector`.  So, the compiler looks for the unqualified `lower_bound()` function in *BOTH* the global namespace *AND* the `std` namespace, finding the latter.