# Why `std::ostream& operator<<` overriding must be declare in 'global' scope in C++?

Tags: c++

### Description

I'm overriding `<< operator` for `std::ostream` to ease object display in my code.
I use differents namespaces where I define types of object to display.

That leads me to a compilation error. I have found a fix. It seems that overriding must be declare in a global scope but I really don't understand why. Can someone explain what cause the error ?

### Error

```
main.cpp:22:38: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream’ and ‘std::vector’)
         std::cout <<"printVector = " << data << std::endl;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

### Sample code (don't compile)

Here is a dummy exemple to show the error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

inline std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& strm, std::vector<uint8_t>& buffer)
{
    return strm << "display std::vector<uint8_t>";
}
    
namespace aNamespace {
    enum TestEnum { a, b, c };
    
    inline std::ostream&
    operator<<(std::ostream& strm, TestEnum& value)
    {
        return strm << "display TestEnum";
    }
  
    static void printVector () 
    {
        std::vector<uint8_t> data {1, 12, 56, 241, 128};
        std::cout <<"printVector = " << data << std::endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    aNamespace::printVector();
    return 0;
}
```

### Environnement

C++11; GCC; Linux

### Sample code fix (**edited**)

Here is a fix version of code for those who are interresed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

inline std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& strm, std::vector<uint8_t>& buffer)
{
    return strm << "display std::vector<uint8_t>";
}

namespace aNamespace {
    using ::operator<<;

    enum class TestEnum { a, b, c };
    
    inline std::ostream&
    operator<<(std::ostream& strm, TestEnum value)
    {
        return strm << "display TestEnum";
    }

    static void printVector () 
    {
        std::vector<uint8_t> data {1, 12, 56, 241, 128};
        std::cout <<"printVector = " << data << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    aNamespace::printVector();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another casualty of ADL.

Comment: Try adding `using ::operator<<;`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but those `inline`s don't accomplish anything. `inline` means that it's okay to have multiple definitions of the inline function in different translation units, and that you promise that they'll all be identical. Since there is only one translation unit here, there's no reason to have it. If you defined that operator in a header file you'd mark it inline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**ADL strikes again**

For resolving operator overloads, C++ uses [Argument Dependent Lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup). In short, it will search the namespace of either parameter (in this case namespace `std`) and the namespace of the call of the operator (`aNamespace`), going up the hierarchy *if no operator overload is found*.

The namespace `std` does not contain any matching overload, but it contains other non-matching overloads, so parent namespace is not searched.

Now, if namespace `aNamespace` does not contain any overload of `operator <<`, parent namespace (global) is searched and correct overload is found, like in your "Sample code fix" example.
However, if it contains any overload for `operator <<`, even a non-matching one, lookup will not consider the parent namespace and the correct overload cannot be found.

This is one of the reasons why some C++ gurus advocate against extensive use of namespaces, or at least to limit it to a single namespace per project (see for example [this article](https://abseil.io/tips/130) by Titus Winters).

---

One possible fix is as you listed, but it may have problems itself, when compiler will look for overload using `aNamespace::TestEnum`. Prefer to have operator overload in the namespace which encapsulates one of the arguments.

Better solution would be to explicitly add operators from global scope to your namespace scope or function scope:

```
 using ::operator<<;
```