# C++ friend operator definition inside class body serves as function declaration?

Tags: c++, friend-function

I'm a newbie reading the *C++ Primer* book. It says:

> A friend declaration only specifies access. It is not a general declaration of the function. If we want users of the class to be able to call a friend function, then we must also declare the function separately from the friend declaration. To make a friend visible to users of the class, we usually declare each friend (outside the class) in the same header as the class itself.

But I just found that this is **not** the case for friend operator functions defined inside the class body. In the following code, `f` could not be found but `operator+` is found:

```
struct X
{
    friend void f()
    {
        // friend functions can be defined in the class
        // this does NOT serve as a declaration, even though this is already a definition
        // to use this function, another declaration is REQUIRED
    }

    friend X operator+(const X & x1, const X & x2)
    {
        // this stuff serves as declaration somehow
        return {x1.v + x2.v};
    }

    void foo()
    {
        f();                    // ERROR: no declaration for f
        X tmp = X {1} + X {2};  // CORRECT
    }

    int v;
};
```

Could someone tell me what makes this difference?
I am using g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, as a reference.
I have searched many questions involving friend declaration and definition on StackOverflow but did not find an answer on this. Sorry if this question is duplicated.

Comment: In your example, you have to forward declare `f()` before the definition of struct `X`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if we define the function inside the class, we must still provide a declaration outside of the class itself to make that function visible. A declaration must exist even if we only call the friend from members of the friendship granting class. This means in your example, you should **forward declare** the function `f` as shown below:

```
//forward declare f
void f();

struct X
{
    //no ADL here since this function f has no parameters of type X. So we also need to declare this outside struct X which we did by providing forward declaration
    friend void f()
    {
        
    }

    void foo()
    {
        f();                    // WORKS NOW because of the forward declaration
        X tmp = X {1} + X {2};  //operator+ found using ADL
    }
    //other members here
};
```

The output of the program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/tntDf1r_H).

The reason why the call to `operator+` works is because of [`ADL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup) which stands for **argument dependent lookup**. In particular, `operator+` can be found using ADL since it has parameters of type `X`. So in this case, you do not need to explicitly declare `operator+` outside struct `X`.

Comment: Thanks so much, man! I have a further question: for `f` and `operator+` in my code, is it considered "declared inside struct X" or "not declared at all"? C++ Primer says it is "not a general function declaration", which is vague. If it is not declared at all: ADL is also name lookup, how can name lookup find something not even declared?

Comment: @AXIHIXA In your case, both `f` and `operator+` are *non-member functions*. When you defined them inside struct `X`they both are considered to be part of the enclosing namespace(which is global namespace in your case), but still the function `f` is **not visible** through *ordinary lookup*. On the other hand, the `operator+` has parameters of type `X` so `operator+` can be found using *argument dependent lookup(also know as ADL)*.

Comment: @AXIHIXA Friend declarations are just like other function declarations. Except that they may or may not be visible to the users, depending upon the type of their parameters(if any).

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the `operator+` takes `X` as parameter, then [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) could [find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) the name; `f` takes nothing, ADL can't help any.

(emphasis mine)

> Names introduced by friend declarations within a non-local class X become members of the innermost enclosing namespace of X, but **they do not become visible to ordinary name lookup (neither unqualified nor qualified) unless a matching declaration is provided at namespace scope**, either before or after the class definition. **Such name may be found through ADL which considers both namespaces and classes**.