# How do parentheses around the function name change which function is called?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I could not understand the second foo call in the code below. How does it call global foo function.  Why does (foo) call  struct A's int()? Can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace MySpace{
    struct A{
        operator int () const {
            cout <<"operator" << endl;
           return 1;        
        }
    };
    
    void foo(A){
        std::cout<< "1" << endl;
    }
}

void foo(int){
    std::cout << "--2" << endl;
}


int main()
{
    
    MySpace::A x;
    foo(x);
    (foo)(x);
   
    return 0;
}
```

I could not understand the second foo call. How does it call global foo function.  Why does (foo) call  struct A's int()? Can you help me?

Comment: It is because of Argument-dependent lookup https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

Comment: you should include the output in the quesiton

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "Argument-Dependent Lookup" (aka ADL, or "Koenig Lookup")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup)

Answer (score 3):

The 1st one works because [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) finds `MySpace::foo` and it wins in overload resolution against `::foo` and gets called.

For the 2nd one, adding parentheses like `(foo)` prevents ADL; then `MySpace::foo` can't be found, only `::foo` is found and gets called. `A` is converted to `int` implicitly (by `A`'s conversion operator) for it to be called.

BTW: You can mark the conversion operator as `explicit` to forbid the implicit conversion from `A` to `int`. Then the 2nd one would fail. E.g.

```
namespace MySpace {
    struct A{
         explicit operator int () const {
            cout <<"operator" << endl;
           return 1;        
        }
    };
    
    void foo(A){
        std::cout<< "1" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: why does it prevent ADL? Perhaps something with foo decaying to function pointer in `(foo)` ? (and without argument there is no ADL)

Comment: cppref has an example about adding `()` but I didnt find their explanation yet

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number ADL requires function all expression to be an *unqualified-id*; `foo` is, but `(foo)` is not.