# Ambiguity while working with namespaces: Can `using` single thing leak anything else?

Tags: c++, namespaces, using-declaration

I have problem with ambiguity while working with namespaces.

Code:

```cpp
namespace app::hal {
    enum class Motor {
        Left  = 0,
        Right = 1
    };

    void setMotor(Motor which, float duty);
}

namespace app::control {
    using Motor = app::hal::Motor;

    void setMotor(Motor which, float duty);
    float getMotor(Motor which);

}

inline void test() {
    using app::control::setMotor;
    using app::control::Motor;
    setMotor(Motor::Left, 0);
}
```

Error:

```
<source>:24:17: error: call of overloaded 'setMotor(app::hal::Motor, int)' is ambiguous
   24 |         setMotor(Motor::Left, 0);
      |         ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:15:14: note: candidate: 'void app::control::setMotor(Motor, float)'
   15 |         void setMotor(Motor which, float duty);
      |              ^~~~~~~~
<source>:8:14: note: candidate: 'void app::hal::setMotor(Motor, float)'
    8 |         void setMotor(Motor which, float duty);
      |              ^~~~~~~~
```

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/sqr4qKbd8

What is going on here? Why is `setMotor` call finding `app::hal::setMotor` as possibility when I didn't `using namespace app::hal` nor `using app::hal::setMotor`? Isn't this "leaking" namespace?

I don't want to change `app::hal` contents, and I wanted so have same naming scheme for `app::control`. How can I make it work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup

Comment: *I don't want to change `app::hal` contents* Use the full name.

Comment: The simplest way to make it work would be to add parenthesis around `setMotor` so that no ADL happens as in `(setMotor)(Motor::Left, 0)`.

Comment: I would use an alias like `namespace appcon = app::control;` and then call the function like `appcon::setMotor(....)`

Comment: What pains me the most is that I wasted close to hour to think over this already, and I am starting to think the best thing to do would be just making changes to `app::hal`, like naming it `setMotorRaw`, which would by the way invalidate all current `app::hal::setMotor` already used in my codebase, so I'm forced to consider using the `app::control::setMotor` (which actually wraps the thing with logging & some state keeping). Thank you everyone, I learnt a lot <3

Comment: @AgainPsychoX We can relate, happens all the time in C++ ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is going on here?

This is due to [ADL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup). Basically, here the namespace `app::hal` will be automatically searched and so there are two `setMotor`(one due to ADL and other because you explicitly specified `using app::control::setMotor`) and hence the ambiguity.

---

> How can I make it work? I **don't want to change** app::hal contents

##### Method 1

You can ***disable(workaround) ADL*** by adding parenthesis around `setMotor` when calling the function as shown below:

```
inline void test() {
    using app::control::setMotor;
    using app::control::Motor;
//--v--------v---------------------->adding parenthesis make this work because NO MORE ADL with parenthesis
    (setMotor)(Motor::Left, 0);   //works now with parenthesis 
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Gq8jsj1Po)

---

##### Method 2

Or you can be explicit about the call as shown below:

```
inline void test() {
    namespace appcon = app::control;
    appcon::setMotor(appcon::Motor::Left, 0); //works now
}
```

Comment: I feel like if I use this workaround the average reader would be caught off guard and be curious. Despite it leads to learning another interesting quick of C++, I think I should keep the reader away from wondering why it's necessary in the first place. Thank you for mentioning it tho.

Comment: @AgainPsychoX I agree but since you asked for a workaroud I delivered.  I am adding another method/workaround which is basically to be explicit like suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77945033/ambiguity-while-working-with-namespaces-can-using-single-thing-leak-anything/77945060#comment137413085_77945033). That way there would be no surprises.