# Why I have to write std::cout and not also std::<<

Tags: c++

Why do I have to write `std::cout` and not also `std::<<` in a line of code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!";
    return 0;
}
```

`cout` comes from `std` library, and isn't `<<` usually used to do bits shifting? So, why don't I have to write the scope operator `::` also before `<<`, since it is used also with another meaning? How the compiler knows that after `std::cout`, `<<` means another thing?

Comment: Argument dependent lookup

Comment: This behavior is also known as Koenig lookup or ADL

Comment: If you were going to fully-qualify the `<<`, by the way, then it would have to look like `std::operator<<(std::cout, "Hello, world!");`. The C++ syntax doesn't let you write `std::cout std::<< "Hello, world!"` to mean the same thing because the notion of namespaces doesn't apply to the operators themselves, it applies to the names of the functions that overload them, which are `operator<<` etc.

Comment: +1 for coming up with this. It's not something many people come up with on their own.

Comment: Others have already mentioned argument dependent lookup (aka Koenig lookup). I think it's worth adding that this is *precisely* the original reason Andrew Koenig invented argument dependent lookup in the first place. It arises in other places, but insertion into (and extraction from) iostreams was what prompted it to start with.

Comment: Related : [_Why GCC allows calling this function without using its namespace first?_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7965262/1870232)

Comment: The same thing happens with e.g. `std::complex` and `operator+`, and even more commonly with many `operator==`. Streams are not some special case.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

First, the compiler will look at the types to the left and right of `<<`. `std::cout` is of type `std::ostream`, the string literal is of type *array of 15 `const char`*. As the left is of class type, it will search for a function named `operator<<`. The question is, where will it look?

The lookup for this name `operator<<` is a so-called unqualified lookup, because the function name isn't qualified like `std::operator<<`. Unqualified lookup for function names invokes argument-dependent lookup. The argument-dependent lookup will search in the classes and namespaces associated with the argument types.

When you include `<iostream>`, a free function of the signature

```
template<typename traits>
std::basic_ostream<char, traits>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, traits>&,
                                             const char*);
```

has been declared in namespace `std`. This namespace is associated with the type of `std::cout`, therefore this function will be found.

`std::ostream` is just a typedef for `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>`, and the *array of 15 `const char`* can be converted implicitly to a `char const*` (pointing to the first element of the array). Therefore, this function can be called with the two argument types.

There are other overloads of `operator<<`, but the function I mentioned above is the best match for the argument types and the one selected in this case.

---

A simple example of argument-dependent lookup:

```
namespace my_namespace
{
    struct X {};

    void find_me(X) {}
}

int main()
{
    my_namespace::X x;
    find_me(x);       // finds my_namespace::find_me because of the argument type
}
```

---

N.B. As this function is a operator, the actual lookup is a bit more complex. It is looked up via qualified lookup in the scope of the first argument (if that's of class type), i.e. as a member function. *Additionally*, unqualified lookup is performed, but ignoring all member functions. The result is slightly different, because unqualified lookup is actually like a two-step procedure, where argument-dependent lookup is the second step. If the first step finds a member function, the second step is not performed, i.e. argument-dependent lookup is *not* used.

Compare:

```
namespace my_namespace
{
    struct X
    {
        void find_me(X, int) {}
        void search();
    };
    void find_me(X, double) {}

    void X::search() {
        find_me(*this, 2.5); // only finds X::find_me(int)
        // pure unqualified lookup (1st step) finds the member function
        // argument-dependent lookup is not performed
    }
}
```

to:

```
namespace my_namespace
{
    struct X
    {
        void operator<<(int) {}
        void search();
    };
    void operator<<(X, double) {}

    void X::search() {
        *this << 2.5; // find both because both steps are always performed
        // and overload resolution selects the free function
    }
}
```

Comment: As a Computer Scientist, this is the correct answer. As an engineer, I have a shorter answer : "_By design_. Namespaces are designed to require a limited amount of extra qualification. Enough to disambiguate, but not more than that."

Comment: BTW, ADL can be disabled by enclosing the function name in parentheses: `(find_me)(x)`. I don't know if/how that works for operator syntax.

Comment: @Matthias Interesting. For operators, you can either stop unqualified lookup e.g. via a using-declaration (member functions are still found) or you can use the explicit syntax `(operator<<)(std::cout, "Hello, world!")`. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccef674c0e505168)

Answer (score 9):

In `std::cout << "Hello, world!"; //calls std:::operator <<`

This is achieved with Argument-dependent name lookup (ADL, aka [*Koenig Lookup*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup))

Although we have only one `std` qualifier but there are two things that comes up from `std` namespace

- `cout`
- `<<`

Without ADL, (Koenig Lookup)

`std::cout std:: << "Hello World" ;//this won't compile`

In order to compile it, we need to use it more uglier form

`std::operator<<(std::cout, "Hello, world!");`

So to avoid such ugly syntax we must appreciate Koenig Lookup :)

Answer (score 3):

The compiler sees that the arguments to << are an std::ostream object and a string, and so is able to locate the proper operator<< definition based on this.

You can sort of think of the argument types of an operator (or really, any function) as part of its name.