# How are we allowed to chain together the insertion operator and other operators in general in C++?

Tags: c++, operators

I'm trying to understand the underlying process in C++ that allows us to form the following expression in C++:

```
cout << "Hello," << "World" << a + b;
```

From my understanding, first, the insertion operator takes the ostream object `cout` and the string literal `"Hello"` as operands and the expression returns a type of `cout` and thus `cout` is now the type of the next string literal and finally also the type of the expression `a + b`.

I'm having trouble understanding the technical details of this process, I understand references are involved which allow us to do this ?

Comment: Suggested Reading : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19122747/1870232

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> From my understanding, first, the insertion operator takes the ostream object cout and the string literal "Hello" as operands and the expression returns a type of cout...

Good so far...

> and thus cout is now the type of the next string literal and finally also the type of the expression a + b.

I'm not sure what you're trying to say here. Maybe it'll help if the operators are grouped according to precedence:

```
(((cout << "Hello,") << "World") << (a + b));
```

The first time `operator<<` is called, its arguments are `cout` and `"Hello"`, as you said. That returns `cout`. Then, the second time, the arguments are `cout` (the result of the previous one) and `"World"`. Then, the third time, the arguments are `cout` and the result of `a + b`.

Maybe it will help further to rewrite the code using the (technically incorrect, see @DavidRodríguez-dribeas's comment) function call syntax:

```
operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(cout, "Hello,"), "World"), a + b);
```

Because each time `operator<<` is called it returns `cout`, the first argument of each call will be `cout`.

Comment: So, what is actually returned from the first expression cout << "Hello" ? A pointer to cout ?

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm A reference to `cout`. The same `cout` object, not a copy.

Comment: Small note: The syntax using `operator<<` is not correct, it helps with the understanding (no negative vote here) but is incorrect. It is tricky to expand operators into the equivalent function syntax, as operators might be implemented as free functions or member functions, and the function syntax equivalent will be different.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Oh, good point. Added a little note about that.

Answer (score 5):

You can think of the `<<` operator as being implemented something like this in terms of stdio functions (consider strings only for now):

```
ostream &operator <<(ostream &stream, const string &data)
{
    fprintf(stream, "%s", data.c_str());
    return stream;
}
```

This code doesn't work exactly as written because the first argument to `fprintf` should be a `FILE*`, not an `ostream`. But that's not important. The important part relevant to your question is the `return stream;` at the end, which returns the same stream you passed in back to the caller. With that, you can chain calls together.

The expression

```
cout << a << b;
```

is the same as

```
(cout << a) << b;
```

The result of `(cout << a)` is `cout` again (plus the side effect of actually printing the value of `a`).

Answer (score 1):

The shift operators `<<` group left to right. So statement

```
cout << "Hello," << "World" << a + b;
```

corresponds to expression

```
( ( ( cout << "Hello," ) << "World" ) << a + b );
```

In expression

```
cout << "Hello,"
```

there is used overloaded operator function << for left operand of type `std::basic_ostream` and right operand of type `const char *`

```
template<class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<charT,traits>&, const charT*);
```

It returns reference to `basic_ostream`. 
`std::cout` is defined as an object of type `basic_iostream<char>`

So after executing

```
cout << "Hello,"
```

you get reference to `std::cout`. which in turn becomes the left  operand of expression

```
cout << "World"
```

and at last returned reference of the above expression becames the left operand of expression

```
cout << a + b
```

where a and b as I suppose are some arithmetic types. This expression is a call of overload operator function for `std::basic_ostream` and this arithmetic type.

As this operator returns refernce to `std_basic_ostream` or more precisely to `std::cout` it becames the return type of the full expression.