# swap fails in case of int and works in case of string

Tags: c++, swap

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>    
int main()
{
 std::string str1 = "good", str2 = "luck";
 swap(str1,str2); /*Line A*/
 int x = 5, y= 3;
 swap(x,y); /*Line B*/
}
```

If I comment Line B the code compiles(http://www.ideone.com/hbHwf) whereas commenting Line A the code fails to compile(http://www.ideone.com/odHka) and I get the following error:

```
error: ‘swap’ was not declared in this scope
```

Why don't I get any error in the first case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`swap(str1, str2)` works because of [Argument dependent lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup)

P.S: [Pitfalls of ADL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958648/what-are-the-pitfalls-of-adl)

Answer (score 4):

You're not qualifying `swap`; it works when passing in `std::string` objects because of [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup), but as `int` does not reside in namespace `std` you must fully qualify the call:

```
std::swap(x, y);
```

or use a using declaration:

```
using std::swap;
swap(x, y);
```

Answer (score 2):

strings are in the std:: namespace, so the compiler looks for swap() for strings there. ints are not, so it doesn't. You want:

```
std::swap(x,y);
```

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you should be using `std::swap()` instead of `swap()`.