# is it possible to hide an overloaded method while using private inheritence in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, private-inheritance

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int fn()
    {
        return 1;
    }
    int fn(int i)
    {
        return i;   //2nd fn()
    }
};
class Bar:Foo
{
public :
    Foo::fn;
};
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Bar b;
    cout<<b.fn(2)<<endl;
}
```

is to possible to hide fn(int) in the concrete class "Bar"

Comment: format your code please, we are humans, not compilers

Comment: Would you want `cout<<b.fn(2)<<endl;` to be compiler error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK no, you cannot 'hide' names from namespaces. This related to *names*, so that includes all possible overloads of the same name.

Similarly, there is no way to `unusing` a name/namespace.

This very phenomenon leads to the rather little-known [ADL Pitfall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958648/what-are-the-pitfalls-of-adl) that library writers should always be aware of.

---

**PS.** in the sample code, of course you could just drop the line saying `/*using*/ Foo::fn;` line... but I guess that is not your actual code....

Answer (score 1):

just make the base class `private`, `protected` (it's `private` by default when using `class`, so far it,s ok) and don't use, but override the function in the derived class

```
class Bar: private Foo
{
public:
    int fn() {return Foo::fn();}
};
```

This will only make only `int fn()` visible in Bar and `not int fn(int)`. Of course, the compiler will cry out loud, that fn is not a virtual function, yet you still override it, but as long as it only calls the one in the base class, its all the same.

Comment: This doesn't override the method `int fn()`, it instead _hides_ it by declaring a new identifier in the enclosed namespace. I don't think `it is all the same`: with virtual, the class layout could be different, ; different optimizations would apply and the semantics of the class when subclassed would be different. I would agree that, in your sample, the observed behaviour (other than performance) would be the same. It is a good workaround for the OP +1