# ADL versus scope-resolution -- which to prefer?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

How do I tell whether I should use

```
my_type bar;
using some_namespace::foo;
foo(bar);
```

instead of

```
some_namespace::foo(bar);
```

when calling my function `foo` (that is not within my immediate scope)? Is there a generic "rule" for figuring out whether you should use ADL or not? Which one should I use "by default"?

Comment: @ybungalobill: Why? It seems pretty similar to what's [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup#Criticism)... where's the mistake?

Comment: You can't take a piece of code out of context, add yet another piece of code and assume it has the same meaning. ADL is behavioral feature, not syntactic one. I.e. you have to say what `foo`s are declared in your program to determine whether ADL is used in the unqualified version or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not ADL.  In both of your examples, `foo` is found via normal lookup.  An example using ADL would be as follows:

```
namespace ns {
    class A { };
    void f(A) { };
}

int main() {
    f(A());
}
```

Here, `f` is not found via normal lookup, but it is found via argument-dependent lookup (because it is in namespace `ns` alongside `A`).  In any case...

Avoid ADL wherever possible.

ADL is beneficial in certain, specific scenarios, for example for operator overloading and for the swappable concept.  However, it should be used sparingly, as it leads to [bizarre, unexpected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958648/what-are-the-pitfalls-of-adl) in many other cases.

Comment: Hmm.. wait but what about something like `swap`, where it's defined in both the std namespace and in the class? Wouldn't that require a `using std::swap;`? Where is the mistake in my example? (Mine looks a lot like what's [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup#Criticism).)

Comment: In your example, the only usable `foo` is the one brought in from `some_namespace`, so there is no `foo` to be found through ADL.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The code you posted in question compares a qualified versus unqualified call. While it's true the the first may involve ADL, it's still not "The ADL". Yes, it's common to use `using` together with ADL, but you can't compare it with qualified calls because it is a completely different feature.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: I think you missed my point. The point is that the person who **defines** `my_type` *may or may not* define the function. It's not my choice whether the client defines that function or not. So my question was whether I should *allow* that "by default" or not -- but *obviously* if there is no such function, then it won't be found via ADL...

Comment: Please post _complete examples_ that _clearly demonstrate_ what you are asking.  Nothing in your question demonstrates what you describe in your comment.  In any case, the answer is no different:  avoid ADL except in the specific cases where it is useful.